# Respuesta borrada y duplicada

Tags: discusión, votos, comentarios

Veo que una usuaria ha publicado dos respuestas casi iguales a la misma pregunta.

En la [primera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/49488/301) voté negativo con explicación y fue borrada por la propietaria.

Y la [segunda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/49630/301) tiene alguna mejora pero sigue estando mal.

Con lo que tengo que copiar el comentario explicando el mismo error y volver a votar negativo. Esto no sería necesario si hubiese editado su respuesta que sería la mejor forma de actuar.

¿Es esta una forma de actuar legítima? ¿Va a ser la nueva moda el borrar una pregunta si recibes negativos y volver a publicarla duplicada con cambios mínimos? ¿O debo pedir que actue un moderador?

Comment: @Jorgesys lo que se cuestiona en esta pregunta es la actitud de un usuario frente a duplicar su respuesta solo para evitar el voto negativo. Eso simplemente está mal.

Comment: En efecto, y ni si quiera se preocupan por los novatos, así como algunos novatos tampoco se preocupan por los usuarios con alta reputación. Los votos deberían estar justificados, ya que dar un voto en contra o a favor se queda corto, e incita más a echar miembros "trolls" (Novatos con dificultades.) de la comunidad que a enseñarles. Lo que sí sería viable es dejar de darle permiso a alguien que lleva un recuento de publicaciones reportadas, y que el reporte sea coherente y no porque la mayoría se invente una paranoya va a ser que borren la pregunta tampoco. Un poco de cordura...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ¿Es esta una forma de actuar legítima?

**No.**

> ¿Va a ser la nueva moda el borrar una pregunta si recibes negativos y volver a publicarla duplicada con cambios mínimos?

**No.**

> ¿O debo pedir que actue un moderador?

**SI.**

No es una actitud aceptable. Si te encuentras estos casos lo recomendable es que lo reportes y no intentes intervenir ya que no puedes hacer nada al respecto.

Lo que va a suceder es que:

- Se va a advertir al usuario de que eso no es algo que se deba hacer.
- Si es reincidente se va a aplicar algún tipo de sanción.
- Según el caso las múltiples respuestas se van a fusionar y/o refactorizar para que solo exista una única (preferiblemente la primera).

Answer (score 4):

En este caso, estoy totalmente de acuerdo. Si mi respuesta recibe votos negativos, no sería muy honesto de mi parte de borrar la respuesta y agregar una nueva como mecanismo para evitar los votos negativos.

Entiendo que recibir votos negativos puede ser frustrante, sobre todo si no estamos de acuerdo con los votantes. Pero esto no justifica este tipo de comportamiento. Hay que respetar el derecho de la comunidad de votar a favor o en contra, estén en lo correcto o no.

En este caso, yo reportaría la nueva respuesta para atención a los moderadores incluyendo los detalles necesarios para que puedan ver la relación a la respuesta anterior, tal como hicistes en esta pregunta meta.

En cuanto a este usuario en particular, nadie puede negar el valor de su participación y de sus aportes en general. Francamente, el sitio le debe un gran reconocimiento. Sin embargo, esto no cambia el hecho que esta es por lo menos la segunda vez que yo personalmente noto este tipo de comportamiento de su parte, y sé que la vez anterior [un moderador le avisó de no repetir este tipo de acción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/37789/18951).

Answer (score 3):

Creo que las respuestas son muy obvias:

> ¿Es esta una forma de actuar legítima?

**No, ya que no esta de acuerdo a las leyes o a la justicia.**

> ¿Va a ser la nueva moda el borrar una pregunta si recibes negativos y
>   volver a publicarla duplicada con cambios mínimos?

**No, es una actitud no aceptada.**

> ¿O debo pedir que actue un moderador?

**Si lo consideras puedes acudir a un moderador.**

Comment: @Todoelmundo. He editado la respuesta de Jorgesys para que sea valida y de calidad. Todo lo referente a cosas personales no son para esta preguntas. Jorgesys, te recomiendo que o bien abras una nueva pregunta en meta para poner lo que comentabas o bien tengamos una charla privada cuando te vaya bien para hablar del tema. Jose, lo mismo te digo.

Comment: @MiquelColl Gracias por la atención Miquel , de hecho considero que este tipo de detalles no se deben estar mostrando (pero en un momento me desesperé), si hay algo que arreglar entre usuarios, creo que debemos realizarlo en un chat room , http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1482/95 , no creo necesario que deba abrir una pregunta, simplemente hay una inconformidad, molestia  o algo que desconozco ya que siempre salgo en sus comentarios, si quiere realizar comentarios acerca de alguna situación, podemos realizarlo en un chat room.  ᕦ ´• ᴥ •` ᕥ

Comment: @MiquelColl: Mi primera impresión es que tu edición fue un abuso de los privilegios de moderador diamantado, pero al ver que la edición mas reciente es del autor, y luego su comentario, cambié de opinión. (no se había refrescado la página). El punto es que como moderador diamantado en casos como este está muy bien que llames a una conversación privada, pero deberías ser paciente en lo que respecta a editar este tipo de publicaciones, dejarlo sólo para casos extremos o bien cuando no hay respuesta en un tiempo razonable por parte del autor y/o implicados.

Comment: @Rubén en el momento en que se pone "ruido" en una respuesta para atacar a un usuario/dejarlo en evidencia no hay paciencia alguna. Lo correcto (y siempre intento preguntar antes a moderadores con experiencia) es lo que he echo + un comentario para aclarar la situacion. Te garantizo que como moderador actuo imparcialmente y ante cualquier duda siempre pregunto primero. Puede que no sea la mejor manera pero creo que era la mas efectiva y correcta

Comment: @MiquelColl: Me parece que podemos hablar más de esto, tal vez en el chat. Luego me pongo en contacto contigo para ponernos de acuerdo.