# 2017 Elección de Moderador - Cuestionario

Tags: discusión, elecciones

En conexión con las elecciones de moderadores, tenemos este hilo de preguntas y respuestas para los candidatos. Las preguntas recolectadas [de este hilo anterior](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2390/4) han sido organizadas aquí.  Este espacio será el lugar en donde los candidatos darán sus respuestas.

He seleccionado las preguntas para la lista oficial y se las comparto aquí también. Tenemos 10 preguntas en total, 2 mías y 8 de la comunidad seleccionadas por votos a favor.

**Para los candidatos:**

Primero, los interesados [deben de postularse aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1). Luego podrán continuar con lo siguiente.

La tarea de ustedes es simple - publiquen una respuesta citando cada una de las preguntas y luego compartan sus respuestas a cada pregunta en esa misma respuesta. Para su conveniencia, incluiré todas las preguntas en formato de cita con un espacio entre cada pregunta en donde se pueda insertar la respuesta. Solamente copia la lista (al editar la pregunta) entera y pon tus respuestas entre las preguntas. Por favor considera poner tu nombre al principio de la publicación para que los lectores sepan que eres tú antes de terminar de leer todo lo que has escrito.  Por favor incluye también un enlace a tú entrada de postulación.

En cuanto todas las respuestas hayan sido compiladas, este servirá como una transcripción para los electores en donde puedan ver los pensamientos de sus candidatos.

¡Les deseamos suerte a los candidatos!

**Oh, y en cuanto hayas terminado con las respuestas, por favor deja un enlace al terminar este pedacito de texto, antes de las 3 rayitas (la regla horizontal). Por favor deja los enlaces en la orden de presentación.**

Para ahorrarles tiempo, aquí están las respuestas de los candidatos (en orden de presentación):

- [respuestas de **ArtEze**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2491/4)
- [respuestas de **Álvaro Montoro**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2493/250)
- [respuestas de **Ivan Botero**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2494/24137)
- [respuestas de **Gonzalo Bianchi (gbianchi)**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2496/65)
- [respuestas de **Javier Sanchez (toledano)**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2497/638)
- [respuestas de **lois6b**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2499/15855)
- [respuestas de **Paul Vargas**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2522/65)
- [respuestas de **Jorgesys**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2537/24137)
- [respuestas de **fredyfx**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2542/83)
- [respuestas de **Joel Ibaceta**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2545/65)
- [respuestas de **Carlos Muñoz**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2546/20)

---

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?
> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?
> 3. ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?
> 4. ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano o (2) Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad. ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?
> 5. ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?
> 6. Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?
> 7. Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?
> 8. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?
> 9. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?
> 10. Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

Comment: ¿Los candidatos publicarán aquí directamente? ¿O entregan las respuestas en secreto y luego se publican todas a la vez?

Comment: Sí, aquí directamente se pondrán las respuestas.

Comment: ¿Publicar una respuesta aquí se considera postulación?

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider no, pero no tiene sentido publicar sin postulación, por lo que en ese caso probablemente sea eliminada la respuesta

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider No, uno se postula [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election) solamente.  :)

Comment: Pero [esta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2417/2027) tenia +12

Comment: Quizás a alguno de los que se postularon no les quedó claro: **se espera que respondan a las 10 preguntas acá **

Comment: Esto, observo cierta omisión de preguntas: [una mía](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2393/83), 4.ª en votos, no se ha incluido (podría argumentarse que una parte se parece a [la de Kenny](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2412/83)). Luego [la de JuankGlezz](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2423/83) tampoco está, pese a estar 7.ª.

Comment: @fedorqui y la tuya era precisamente una de las que mas me interesaba a mi. De hecho, yo hice una [pregunta similar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2395/15301) como alguno apuntó (aunque no era igual) y ya que la mia no triunfó esperaba ver la tuya (que en mi opinión no tiene nada que ver con la de Kenny)

Comment: ¿En la respuesta hay que volver a copiar las preguntas o se responde directamente?

Comment: @ArtEze _La tarea de ustedes es simple - publiquen una respuesta citando cada una de las preguntas y luego compartan sus respuestas a cada pregunta en esa misma respuesta. Para su conveniencia, incluiré todas las preguntas en formato de cita con un espacio entre cada pregunta en donde se pueda insertar la respuesta. Solamente copia la lista (al editar la pregunta) entera y pon tus respuestas entre las preguntas_ Debes copiar las preguntas y poner la respuesta a continuación de cada uno entiendo yo

Comment: @ArtEze ahora mismo hay un proceso de elecciones en SOen, echa un vistazo [aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352386/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/352436#352436) para ver un ejemplo de como responden. Si te fijas, luego en tu candidatura debes poner un enlace a tus respuestas,como [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9#post-45159932)

Comment: Me gustaría al menos se aplicara esto: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222154/make-moderator-election-questionnaire-mandatory

Comment: @Jorgesys ¿Te gustaría que se aplicara para estas eleciones or para las próximas?

Answer (score 36):

[Álvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-87842)

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Con paciencia. La idea es que los usuarios que aportan buenas respuestas y de calidad se mantengan y sigan en el sitio, pero eso no significa un “todo vale” para ellos. Si eres un usuario beneficioso, pero tu actitud/comentarios hace que otros usuarios no se sientan cómodos y abandonen el sitio, quizás no seas tan beneficioso.

Si ese “usuario valioso” (o cualquier usuario, valioso o no) genera una gran cantidad de argumentos/reportes, me comunicaría con él/ella usando las herramientas disponibles como el chat o incluso el email, e intentaría ver por qué esos reportes ocurren. Si el comportamiento no deseado continúa, hablaría con los otros moderadores para ver si ellos perciben lo mismo y tomar otras medidas.

> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Con diálogo: hablando se entiende la gente. Quizás esa persona cerró/eliminó/etc la pregunta por algo que es incorrecto… o quizás yo no entendí bien cómo debería ser. En una sala de chat le expondría mis argumentos (citando el centro de ayuda o alguna conversación al respecto en meta), escucharía (o leería) los suyos e intentaría llegar a un acuerdo.

Si no llegamos a un punto en común (lo cual puede pasar), no intentaría deshacer la acción del otro moderador y definitivamente no llevaría una disputa al plano público. Los moderadores, en la medida de lo posible, deberían mantener un frente común con respecto a las acciones tomadas incluso si a veces no están de acuerdo con ellas. Y después analizar con la cabeza fría cómo la comunidad entendió o aceptó esa decisión y aprender con la experiencia.

> 3. ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?

Como usuario, si me encuentro con una pregunta de un tema/tecnología que desconozco en las colas de revisión y no veo ningún error aparente (bien escrita, con un mcve, etc), pulso el botón de “omitir”. No es malo reconocer que no se sabe algo (aunque a veces cuesta).

Creo que como moderador es peor hacer de más que de menos. Intentaría seguir un criterio parecido que como usuario: si en general la pregunta se ve bien y no tiene una “falta grave”, debería ser la comunidad (preferiblemente los usuarios con más experiencia en esas tecnologías) los que se movieran más.

> 4. ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano o (2) Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad. ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?

Prefiero ser permisivo hasta cierto punto. Si la pregunta tiene deficiencias graves o es de muy mala calidad, actuaría directamente. Si la pregunta tiene alguna deficiencia (causa de cierre) pero podría ser interesante para otros usuarios o se podría arreglar con algunas ediciones/añadidos, corregiría los errores personalmente o escribiría un comentario y dejaría que siguiera el flujo normal. Pasado un tiempo prudencial (p.e. 2-3 días laborables), si la pregunta no ha sido modificada y sigue teniendo esas deficiencias, actuaría adecuadamente.

> 5. ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?

Me gustaría pensar que el sitio va a estar mejor: más usuarios, más preguntas, más colaboración… Y que, aunque muchos usuarios no se hayan dado cuenta del trabajo que se hizo tras el telón, el trabajo se hizo y se hizo bien.

> 6. Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?

No. Considero que las preguntas básicas no bajan la calidad del sitio. No todo el mundo nace aprendido y Stack Overflow intenta ser una fuente de conocimiento para programadores de todos los niveles... Y eso incluye preguntas complicadas y preguntas básicas.

Ahora… Comprendo que hay preguntas básicas y “preguntas básicas”. Mientras que hay preguntas básicas de usuarios novatos que mejoran la calidad del sitio, también hay “preguntas básicas” de usuarios que no han hecho ningún tipo de investigación o esfuerzo. Estas últimas generalmente acabarán cerradas por los usuarios de la comunidad como “demasiado amplia” o “no está claro lo que se pregunta”.

> 7. Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?

Todavía no hay muchos usuarios especializados en algunas etiquetas y creo que se podría realizar una limpia: definir contenidos, añadir datos, crear sinónimos… aunque comprendo que la última parte es la única que realmente el moderador estaría involucrado.

En general, creo que las colas de revisión funcionan bien, aunque la de reapertura parece algo más lenta (por el mismo motivo: no todos los usuarios tienen acceso). Agilizarla sería importante para evitar que los usuarios cuya pregunta fue puesta en espera/cerrada, se frustren y se vayan después de editarla.

> 8. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

Con un gran poder, viene una gran responsabilidad. Aunque intentaré que mi trabajo como moderador sea lo más invisible/transparente posible, sé que siempre va a haber alguien que no esté de acuerdo con alguna decisión que tome… ¡pasa ya sin necesidad de ser moderador! No será la primera ni la última vez que algún usuario me llama a un chat, me menciona en meta, o me manda un email a mi correo personal quejándose porque una decisión no le gustó. Como moderador pasará más a menudo pero, como hasta ahora, tomaré decisiones que pueda explicar y justificar de manera lógica o apuntando al centro de ayuda.

> 9. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

Dependería de la urgencia del problema.

Si no es nada urgente, llevaría el problema a los otros moderadores y a meta. Esto es una comunidad y, en la medida de lo posible, son los propios usuarios de la comunidad los que deberían poder decidir en el caso de que algo no esté claro o bien definido.

Si es algo que debe resolverse para ayer, consultaría con los otros moderadores de SOes (presentes y pasados), JuanM o los moderadores de otras comunidades para saber si se encontraron con una situación similar… si ninguno de ellos está disponible, aplicaría el sentido común y realizaría una acción que pudiera justificar lógicamente si se me preguntara por qué lo hice (y alguien preguntará, ver pregunta de arriba).

> 10. Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

Me haría varias preguntas:

- ¿Puede esta publicación ser de ayuda para otros usuarios?
- ¿Si se editara/modificara parcialmente sería salvable?
- ¿Se podría marcar para cerrar por otro motivo?

Si puedo responder “sí”, “sí” y “no”, la conservaría. Pero si la publicación es de mala calidad, no va a ayudar a otros usuarios, es difícil de arreglar/mantener y además podría cerrarse por otro motivo (parece que a menudo respuestas que deberían ser comentarios o respuestas del tipo “yo también tengo este problema” acaban en esa cola), entonces votaría por eliminarla.

Comment: Tus respuestas son impecables. En cuanto a la #5 "*más usuarios, más preguntas, más colaboración*". ¿Esto es algo a lo que dedicarías tiempo *como moderador*? ¿Qué harías? O, si es un objetivo que no está relacionado a tareas de moderador, ¿hay algo que pienses mejor a futuro gracias a tu moderación?

Comment: Cuando hablas de _"preguntas básicas y “preguntas básicas”"_ creo que sé a qué te refieres, pero creo que es criterio de cada uno. algunos _(me incluyo)_ ven la oportunidad de ayudar "ya sea con un comentario, edición, etc", mientras que otros no (pueden pasar de largo o votar negativo, etc) = no es necesariamente malo.

Comment: @Mariano si como moderador puedo limpiar el sitio (encargándome de las preguntas claramente fuera de tema, procesando rápidamente los reportes y las peticiones de usuarios en meta, etc) para que los usuarios no deban preocuparse (excesivamente) de esas cosas y puedan dedicarse a usar el sitio sin obstáculos, creo que eso haría que pasasen más tiempo en SOes preguntando/respondiendo o en el chat/meta con propuestas en lugar de con quejas. Y eso haría el sitio más amigable y colaborativo.

Comment: Cuando dices en la pregunta #3 "**como moderador es peor hacer de más que de menos**", es el tipo de actitud que debería mostrar un moderador. Cuenta con mi apoyo.

Answer (score 20):

[lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-87995)

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Investigaría dichos reportes o disputas independientemente de si el usuario tiene buenas aportaciones al sitio. Y sin duda si esos reportes fueran correctos, y pese a las valiosas publicaciones, hablaría con el usuario en cuestión para resolver los problemas reportados.

> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

La comunicación es fundamental y hablaría con él para que me explicara su punto de vista pero considero que si la cerró/eliminó/etc sin ningún tipo de debate con el resto de moderadores fue que lo tenía muy claro, y su decisión cuenta tanto como la mía.

> 3. ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?

Respecto a las preguntas de esta clase, mi moderación se ha basado en la edición para el correcto formato (estético y de contenido como mcve) de la misma.

Dejaría que los usuarios con conocimientos de esa tecnología decida qué hacer con esa pregunta.

> 4. ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano o (2) Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad. ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?

Ante estos casos hay que ser paciente. No se puede esperar de alguien nuevo que tenga un publicación perfectamente estructurada y válida. Con explicaciones y guías se conseguirá que en el futuro sus publicaciones sean mejores y que el usuario mismo esté mas a gusto en el sitio.

Sin embargo, hay preguntas que parece que son dejadas en el olvido y pasado un tiempo si voto para el cierre. Salvo con las preguntas en inglés que es un voto inmediato con su oportuno comentario al autor.

> 5. ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?

Este sitio no es como pueda ser el sitio de Poker o de Hinduismo. Estas juntando la programación y el español.

De este sitio solo se puede esperar que crezca y progrese y espero poder acabar mi moderación contento con el curso que va siguiendo el sitio. Usuarios a gusto participando y un ambiente cordial a la par que profesional.

> 6. Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?

Bien es cierto que hay preguntas que no se ha buscado lo suficiente antes de formularse pero las respuestas que pueda recibir pueden ser exquisitas y explicar, lo que en principio pueda parecer básico, de manera clara y detallada.

Además, esa misma duda puede tenerla alguien y buscando en internet puede encontrar la pregunta *básica* ya respondida.

Y eso sube la calidad del sitio, gente que entra para resolver sus dudas y plantear nuevas.

> 7. Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?

Las ediciones, la revisión de la cola, Meta, ... todo eso puede hacerlo un usuario con sus respectivos privilegios.

Me gustaría ser un moderador cercano. Cuando los usuarios nuevos tienen problemas con su publicacion, hablar con ellos y guiarlos. Cuando un usuario consagrado duda en cómo actuar respecto a una disputa, resolver el problema entre todos.

> 8. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

Eso ya pasa sin ser moderador. No me importa que se me cuestione mi actuación ya que cada uno puede tener una opinión.

Lo importante es tomar decisiones razonadas. Y de cada situación se puede sacar algo en claro para futuros casos.

> 9. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

Tenemos a un gerente de la comunidad, hay ex-moderadores, moderadores de otros sitios de la red y gente en el chat siempre dispuesta a dar su opinión. Por falta de gente no estoy preocupado.

> 10. Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

No hay una línea fija que se pueda trazar para separar preguntas. Cada una tiene una situación y un contexto.

Podría evaluar si al autor le han comentado sugerencias para su mejora y qué hizo al respecto. Valoraría también si esa pregunta es *salvable* o si por el contrario tiene potencial. Cada situación es única y haría lo mejor para el sitio.

Comment: *La comunicación es fundamental y hablaría con él para que me explicara su punto de vista pero considero que si la cerró/eliminó/etc sin ningún tipo de debate con el resto de moderadores fue que lo tenía muy claro, y su decisión cuenta tanto como la mía.* esto no me dice cuál es la conclusión final ni a qué llevaría.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza queria decir que no voy a cuestionar su acción, pero que me gustaría hablarlo para ver como llegó a esa decisión. Un saludo

Comment: #5 "*Usuarios a gusto participando y un ambiente cordial a la par que profesional*" es algo que queremos todos para el sitio, pero, ¿hay algo que creas que consideres que mejoraría en el tiempo gracias a *tu moderación*?

Comment: @Mariano, me gusta guiar a los usuarios nuevos con comentarios de mejora en sus publicaciones. Me gustaria que se cree una "cadena de tutelaje" mejorando asi los casos en los que hay *downvotes* sin explicación, cierres sin sugerencias de mejora .. etc.

Answer (score 15):

[Gonzalo Bianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-87895)

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Habría que centrarse sobre el porque de los reportes. El usuario puede tener buenas intenciones, pero nadie es dueño del sitio, y por lo tanto todos nos debemos apegar a las reglas. Si los reportes son constantes sobre los mismos temas, hay que hablar con el, para tratar de evitar que se sigan produciendo los mismo.

> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Confirmaría la razón que llevo al otro moderador a tomar esa acción. En algunas situaciones no todos estamos de acuerdo. Pero si debemos tener una visión en conjunto y tratar de tener las mismas reglas. En caso de duda, no tendría problemas en cuestionarme a mi mismo como actuarían los otros moderadores en la misma situación. Nunca revertiría un cambio sin antes consultarlo. Y de ser absolutamente necesario, aclararía antes con mis compañeros por que tome tal acción y me dejaría juzgar por ellos. Nadie actúa de mala fe y uno comete errores.

> 3. ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?

En este caso sigo los criterios de una pregunta genérica. Busco que la pregunta se entienda, refiera algo de código y explique el problema correctamente. Sin embargo, no todas las tecnologías funcionan igual, y por ejemplo pedir un trace de una consulta `SQL` no tiene sentido. Por lo tanto debo apoyarme si o si en gente con conocimientos en esas tecnologías para poder tomar una decisión final.

> 4. ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano o (2) Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad. ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?

Al principio priorizaba la calidad de las preguntas. Sin embargo, esta es una comunidad en pleno crecimiento. Muchos de los usuarios mas experimentados no pasan por aquí, simplemente porque saben que preguntando en ingles seguro reciben una respuesta mas rápido. Me gusta decir que somos un nene chiquito que esta creciendo, por lo tanto nuestros usuarios tienen que crecer con nosotros. Seria permisivo orientando al usuario a mejorar su pregunta. Si después de un tiempo sigue siendo de mala calidad, la eliminaría.

> 5. ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?

Me gustaría que quede un sitio con una base de usuarios calificados mayor. Si mejoramos las preguntas porque nuestros usuarios cada vez saben mas, entonces podemos atraer a toda la base que sigue preguntando en ingles por miedo a no encontrar respuestas en este sitio. También me gustaría dejar nuevos usuarios con conocimientos en edición y automoderación del sitio.

> 6. Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?

Desgraciadamente si, pero la mayoría de las preguntas básicas se encuentran también en StackOverflow en ingles, por lo cual el problema en realidad es como hacer buenas esas preguntas básicas. Como concatenar dos campos en cualquier lenguaje es una pregunta básica. Sin embargo no son malas si ayudan a que el sitio reciba trafico y a que nuevos usuarios nos descubran. Solo hay que hacerlas bonitas.

> 7. Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?

Aparte de la etiqueta mercadopago, que esta casi huérfana y no parece que tenga una solución desde el lado de la moderación, creo que lo principal es que el sitio tenga una identidad. No es fácil tener una mezcla de tecnologías y tipos de preguntas en un solo sitio (no existe base de datos español, o code golfer). Por lo tanto trataría de hacer que las preguntas tengan las etiquetas correctas, y no etiquetas de mas. Un usuario con conocimientos así podría identificar mas fácilmente las preguntas que le interesan. También trataría de evitar el cierre indiscriminado de preguntas por desconocimiento.

> 8. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

No tengo ningún problema con esto. Se que ser moderador de una comunidad implica que a uno lo vean como "jefe" y por lo tanto ser escudriñado todo el tiempo. Soy abierto a las criticas y reconozco mis errores cuando me los hacen notar. Tengo varios años en varias comunidades de StackExchange, y se que nosotros trabajamos para el beneficio conjunto. Yo he criticado decisiones de mis pares, y he aceptado criticas sin ningún problema.

> 9. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

En este caso, lo mejor es lograr un consenso. Hay 3 moderadores, un CM y entre todos podemos tomar una decisión para la comunidad. También hay usuarios con mucho prestigio en la misma, que pueden ayudar a llegar a una mejor conclusión. Si no podemos llegar a una conclusión entre los moderadores o el CM, entonces estaría dispuesto a escuchar mas opiniones. Pero esto es una comunidad. Y por lo tanto las decisiones se toman comunitariamente.

> 10. Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

Somos una comunidad recién nacida en muchos casos. No hay una regla precisa, porque eso seria como tapar el ingreso de usuarios nuevos si no saben preguntar. Muchos usuarios aprendieron a preguntar en base a comentarios  y ayudas con sus preguntas. Trataría de ver la actividad del usuario primero.. si hizo 5 preguntas y las borro todas después de recibir respuestas, seria menos permisivo que un usuario que hizo un par de preguntas malas, logro recibir respuestas y continua preguntando. Trataría de llamarle la atención para que las mejore. Pero si el usuario acepta respuestas y sigue participando, hay que enseñarle. Es como un niño pequeño al cual hay que recordarle muchas veces lo mismo. Pero con el tiempo aprende que es por su bien.

Comment: _Solo hay que hacerlas bonitas._ es lo que iba a decir. Realmente algunas preguntas "y respuestas" necesitan revisión en cuanto a su redacción (es como trabajar con un diamante en bruto).

Comment: #5 "*un sitio con una base de usuarios calificados mayor*" ... Y por lo que te entendí, tu visión es que mejores preguntas atraen a usuarios más calificados pero, al mismo tiempo, estás diciendo que serías permisivo con nuevos usuarios y contenido cuestionable, por lo que no me convence tanto esto de que los usuarios calificados llegarían solos. ¿Tomarías acciones específicas *como moderador* para atraer a este público? O, si no implican acciones de un moderador, ¿hay alguna otra cosa en la que sí creés el sitio mejoraría por vos como moderador?

Comment: El otro dia hablaba con un compañero que esta trabajando con Angular y me contaba que ante la duda iba a SO eng a preguntar... y que igual ahi no recibia respuestas satisfactorias.. Le pregunte porque no preguntaba aqui, y me dice que aqui nadie sabe. Le conte que habia bastante gente que sabia sobre diversos temas.. y que llegado el caso creciamos todos juntos.. creo que lo convenci (pero si no siempre puedo ir a molestarlo en persona). El caso es que si alguien sabe mucho, pero tal vez no sabe preguntar, llevandolo por el buen camino, capaz tenemos alguien valioso encubierto.

Comment: Mi compañero de la pregunta anterior es uno de esos casos.. su expertice no es angular.. pero sabe de desarrollos de inteligencia artificial como nadie.

Answer (score 15):

[**Jorgesys**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-89929)

---

> I) ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de
>   respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de
>   argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Un usuario "valioso" (respuestas valiosas) siempre es bueno en una comunidad, después de todo es alguien que puede hacer crecer a la misma mediante sus aportes. Se debe mantener siempre y cuando no rompa las reglas ya que si las rompe debe ser sancionado, el parámetro usado debe ser el mismo que para cualquier usuario de la comunidad.

Sin duda, se debe tener un acercamiento con estos usuarios, definiendo la razón de los argumentos/reportes.

Estos usuarios "valiosos" como muchos otros, son inteligentes y por eso mismo, creo firmemente que pueden cambiar su actitud para la buena convivencia con la comunidad.

En caso de no llegar a una solución y se reincide, la decision a tomar sería consensuada con los demás moderadores.

> II) ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador
>   cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Una de las principales premisas es consensuar antes de la toma de decisiones, aunque algunas decisiones pueden tomarse individualmente, una mejor decisión siempre se toma en equipo. En este punto es imprescindible la comunicación.

si la pregunta se  cerró/eliminó/etc incorrectamente sin duda la acción sería revertida.

> III) ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de
>   las que no tienes conocimientos?

La cantidad de tecnologías que abarca SO es extensa, es muy posible que algún moderador se encuentre situación, mi respuesta es que otro moderador con conocimiento tome la decisión o incluso documentarme sobre la tecnología para la toma de una decisión.

> IV)  ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de
>   calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene
>   alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo
>   para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano o (2) Ser
>   estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad.
>   ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?

Podemos tener tal vez más usuarios si fuera un foro pero hay que dejar claro que SOes no es un foro, es un sitio de Preguntas y respuestas para programadores y profesionales de la informática.

He visto infinidad de discusiones sobre esto y considero por experiencia de SOen, que las reglas son claras, de lo contrario tendríamos el sitio lleno de preguntas llenas de respuestas no acertadas y preguntas basadas en opiniones.

Todo tiene un limite, pero no hay que caer en ser tan permisivo, si la pregunta es de muy baja calidad, se tiene que guiar al usuario para mejorarla,  si no mejora, sin duda la cerraría. Los usuarios poco a poco conocerán como trabaja el sitio y mejoraran sus preguntas.

Simplemente tomen en cuenta el sitio SOen, ahí no son permisibles en absoluto y el sitio es un éxito.

Todos los usuarios son valiosos, incluso pueden ayudar con un simple comentario que puede ser valioso para la solución del problema.

Mi alternativa es guiar a los usuarios para que lleven a cabo lo definido en el Centro de ayuda y aplicar y aplicar la ley cuando es necesario.

Recuerdo como experiencia cuando me uni a SOen, tuve mis primeras 3 preguntas consecutivas cerradas, lo cual me molesto un poco y cerré la cuenta, pero al ver la necesidad y la importancia de SOen terminé por seguir los lineamientos.

> V) ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo
>   de moderación?

La calidad del sitio aumente y principalmente la atracción de usuarios que pregunten/respondan sobre varias tecnologías, para tener una grandiosa base de datos de información en idioma español para todo el mundo.

Quisiera comentar que estaba en contra de un sitio en español, pero al trabajar con personas muy jóvenes y sugerirles SOen, el principal problema era el idioma, algunos iniciaban el aprendizaje del idioma inglés, es algo que no tomaba en cuenta y me hizo definitivamente cambiar de opinión.

Definitivamente haber contribuido al crecimiento del sitio tanto de usuarios como de la calidad de información, además haber realizado definiciones correspondientes que usuarios consideren faltantes relacionadas al uso de SOen.

> VI) Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de
>   unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la
>   calidad del sitio?

En realidad no creo que preguntas básicas bajen la calidad del sitio, lo importante es estructurar la pregunta de una forma correcta para que pueda ser de utilidad para los desarrolladores.

Incluso estas preguntas pueden tener varias respuestas con una calidad adecuada.

> VII) Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar
>   como moderador.  ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a
>   resolverlo?

Son varios problemas, puedo comentar que uno es principalmente evitar dudas y discusiones sobre que agregar y que no, para esto hay que definir la información necesaria para que no surjan dudas. En otro punto hay que tener claro que el sitio es inclusivo, pero hay que identificar usuarios que provocan problemitas, sugerir comportamiento adecuado, y si es necesario aplicar una sanción .

> VIII) ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y
>   en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones
>   sobre ellas?

No es ningún problema, teniendo la responsabilidad de ser moderador, es inherente el ser cuestionado, y es responsabilidad dar información a los usuarios del sitio.

> IX) Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al
>   menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para
>   saber como responder a la situación?

Se definiría en conjunto con los demás moderadores y por supuesto al gerente de la comunidad. Como he comentado, es importante el trabajo en equipo para la toma de decisiones.

> X) Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como
>   muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de
>   moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas").
>   ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las
>   preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

Me preguntaría principalmente si son de utilidad para la comunidad para determinar conservarlas, algunas pueden incluso ser editadas para tener una calidad aceptable, si no llega a tener calidad simplemente se eliminaría.

Comment: O es falso que te llamas *Jorge Boșca* o es falso que te sintieses discriminada por ser mujer. Y esta falsedad no puede ser accidental o un error. Tus dificultades con el uso del español serán un grave problema a la hora de moderar. Y no respetas las normas; pese a reconocer [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1419/301) que actuastes de forma no legítima todavía no has corregido esa acción no legítima; no has borrado la respuesta que publicaste en segundo lugar cronológicamente.

Comment: Hola Jose Antonio (estoy en elecciones), no es estricto el usar el nombre real para tener un usuario en SO, puedes usar un nickname, alias, a.k.a etc, de hecho "Elenasys", lo había tenido desde que hace ya varios años que ingrese a SO en inglés (algún día les compartiré el porque de "Elenasys").  Considero que ahora tengo un buena nivel de español, te aseguro no tendría problemas en el manejo del idioma, sinceramente estoy tratando de mejorar en idioma Alemán y Francés, que es donde si podría tener problemas.

Comment: En cuanto a la pregunta que indicas, no recordaba estaba abierta y con puntuación negativa, considero tenia información de ayuda a usuarios, pero bueno, ahora que la eliminé me dio puntos de reputación, gracias.

Comment: Absolutamente irrelevante si el nombre del usuario es real o no

Comment: Recuerdo varios casos de comportamiento bastante errático e incluso engañoso: [Pregunta cerrada con votos negativos...](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1942/83). En ella hablas de que _Que bueno que se recupero la pregunta_ mientras [votaste repetidamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/65300/timeline) por borrarla. ¿Podrías exponer tu opinión al respecto? Me preocupa en general que seas un usuario que se "calienta" fácilmente y toma las disputas como algo personal.

Comment: La respuesta es excepcional,  la realizo una persona con experiencia, por eso habría que dar oportunidad de editae la calidad de la pregunta por parte del usuario, lo cual nunca se realizo, quieres preguntas sin calidad en el sitio?. En cuanto a "se calienta" me imagino te refieres, con respecto a mis respuestas a algunos usuarios que en realidad son pocos, tu tomarias comentarios no constructivos de personas que no conoces como algo personal?.

Comment: mi objetivo principal como usuario en este sitio es ayudar y aprender de otros usuarios.  Recuerdo que al inicio no respondía hasta que tome la determinación de hacerlo ya que el objetivo de los comentarios no es obviamente una critica constructiva,  sin embargo como moderador tienes un rol y responsabilidad diferente y obviamente no vas a tomar como prioridad esos comentarios, como ejemplo Juan M, cuando fue criticado y cuestionado injustamente como Gerente de la comunidad.

Comment: @Jorgesys yo te apoyo :`) pero esas preguntas del nik???? enserio son importantes??? para mi no.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo @IvanMoreFlores , saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys cuentanos el significado de Elenasys (te odiaba :D), se sincero, me intigra jajajaja. Apoyo tu postulación, "O es falso que te llamas Jorge Boșca o es falso que te sintieses discriminada por ser mujer" innecesario.

Comment: No me queda clara tu respuesta a mi comentario. Si la respuesta era excepcional, ¿por qué borrar la pregunta? ¿Qué harías en general en casos así de preguntas malas con respuestas excepcionales? Gracias por tus respuestas.

Comment: @dwarandae El nick es irrelevante, lo importante es la mentira. Tienes otro [ejemplo de mentira aquí](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36984968#36984968). En la [lista de revisiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/65327/revisions) se puede comprobar que JorgeSys nunca desprotegió la pregunta. Y ya que estamos, JorgeSys, ¿podrías explicar la edición 15 que has hecho en esa pregunta? ¿Qué aporta añadir esos espacios? Se queda igual la pregunta. Es un caso perfecto de edición minúscula o trivial que el centro de ayuda dice que no se haga.

Comment: Cuando "desprotegí" otra persona lo había realizado. En cuanto al, espacio, ya lo revertí para que no tengas conflicto. Escribiendo desde un móvil en el browser en ocasiones he escrito algo incompleto por error, posteriormente se puede editar. Considero te ahogas en un vaso de agua, trata de ser más abierto, como ejemplo las preguntas y respuestas que realizas en Meta tienen este tinte algunas tiene varios negativos y otras incluso se borraron.

Comment: ¿La mentira?, Jose Antonio, espero que después no me pidas agregar mi foto real. Te sugiero enfocar tus esfuerzos en ayudar a otros desarrolladores y ayudar al sitio que es lo importante (recuerda que no hay pago por esto).

Comment: @sioesi Hola Nicolas, como has estado, muchas gracias, eso que te intriga luego lo platicamos hehe!-

Comment: Todo bien por aqui, tu? @Jorgesys jajajaja espero esa platica saludos!

Comment: Como sabemos que vives en romania, entiendo el uso de números romanos (o rumanios en este caso), lo voy a dejar así.

Comment: Las palabras se las lleva el viento, lo que importa son los hechos. En [esta captura](http://i.imgur.com/lKBTNJ3.png) podemos la verdadera respuesta a la pregunta 1, así trata JorgeSys a otros usuarios, con ataques ad hominem. Sus comentarios y los míos [han sido borrados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91430/301) por los moderadores. A mi me han mandado [un mensaje de moderador](http://i.imgur.com/8kPrUOn.png) por esto, ¿y a él?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos A él también le llegó lo mismo, es para que se calmen y dejen de pelear.

Comment: Si estas en una comunidad trata de convivir adecuadamente, no es correcto tratar de exponer a usuarios, incluso a los moderadores e increiblemente al gerente de [SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1666/nuestro-gestor-de-comunidad-funciona), varias de tus preguntas con cuestionamientos sin razón incluso además de tener puntos negativos, fueron eliminados. Trata de convivir, no busques señalar cuando no hay razón, en este caso porque votar negativo si [no conoces la tecnología](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teYar.png), simplemente hay que omitir.

Comment: El usar esto como bandera, "así trata JorgeSys a otros usuarios, con ataques ad hominem" , es de muy mal gusto. La mayoría buscamos de este sitio cordialidad y que sea el mejor. Se puede [ver en mi perfil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/jorgesys) y ver las respuestas, donde es obvio como interactuo con las personas de una forma amable buscando ayudar retribuyendo lo mismo que obtengo de SOes.

Comment: No creo que cambie gran cosa a estas alturas, pero comparto exactamente las mismas preocupaciones que expuso @fedorqui en su primer comentario, y no he visto que le hayas contestado su última pregunta.  Y voy a agregar una pregunta más: siendo que es bien conocido que no te llevas bien con José Antonio, ¿qué medidas tomarías para mantener la imparcialidad en tu moderación si él está envuelto? ¿Lo dejarías en manos de otro moderador?

Comment: stan, con respecto a este comentario: "siendo que es bien conocido que no te llevas bien con José Antonio ", supongo que no tienes mucha actividad en el sitio, es conocido que a quien mencionas no se lleva bien con varios en el sitio (la razón la desconozco y créeme que trato entenderlo), como ejemplo revisa los comentarios que realiza aquí: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/30/ya-nos-graduamos-ahora-que-sigue/.

Comment: Con respecto a esta pregunta: ¿qué medidas tomarías para mantener la imparcialidad en tu moderación si él está envuelto?, como lo he comentado si tienes un rol diferente tienes una responsabilidad diferente, debes ser objetivo y justo., (me imagino que lo dices porque tu te comportarías igual, lo cual es un error y no debe ser así). Yo soy parte de un equipo y además responsable, créeme que es diferente ser desarrollador a  ser responsable y tomar decisiones de grupo o grupos., además de lograr una buena empatía entre los miembros del equipo.

Comment: "¿por qué borrar la pregunta? ¿Qué harías en general en casos así de preguntas malas con respuestas excepcionales? Gracias por tus respuestas. " Siempre se da oportunidad al OP de mejorar su pregunta para este de acuerdo a la calidad requerida en el sitio,lo cual no sucedio ya que tiene varios votos negativos. Como comente, me preguntaría, si es utíl,  al parecer la respuesta es útil para el OP y además para otros usuarios revisa la cantidad de votos que tiene. La pregunta sin duda es "demasiado amplia", por lo tanto las normas del sitio indican su destino.

Comment: A raíz del comentario de @sstan me doy cuenta Jorgesys que medio contestaste a lo que consultaba. Por favor, acostúmbrate a usar `@` para mencionar a la gente, así recibirán notificación cuando lo hagas. Más información al respecto en [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/83).

Comment: @fedroqui Gracias por tus comentarios.

Answer (score 12):

#### [toledano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-87930)

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Primero consideraría el tipo de reportes, para identificar un comportamiento sistemático. El primer paso es *invitarlo* a corregir dicho comportamiento. Si hay reincidencia, *advertirle* de las consecuencias, con las herramientas que disponga el sitio. Por último, si persiste en el comportamiento reportado, **mi posición es proteger primero a la comunidad.** Por muy buen contenido que genere un individuo, es mi opinión que es más importante el colectivo.

> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró, eliminó, etc., una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

¿Una, solo una? Respetaría su decisión. Debo confiar en su criterio y en el de los usuarios que lo eligieron. Sin embargo,  para que reducir el riesgo que esta situación se repita **promoveré activamente la generación de criterios objetivos comunes** no solo para usuarios con privilegios elevados, sino para cualquier moderador.

> 3. ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?

Aun cuando hay tecnologías que no conozco, estoy convencido que las preguntas en este sitio deben tener ciertas características comunes (generalmente una descripción adecuada, un problema concreto, un mcve). Como norma, la mayoría de las veces esta revisión *genérica* funciona, pero **cada pregunta es y será evaluada de forma objetiva e independiente**, así lo hecho desde que obtuve de los privilegios de moderación y así lo seguiré haciendo.

> 4. ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano o (2) Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad. ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?

Para mi no es un dilema. Estoy convencido que **las preguntas de calidad generan respuestas de calidad** y más aún, la calidad de los contenidos no solo atrae más y mejores visitantes, también contribuye a su retención como usuarios.  Pero no se trata de cerrar las preguntas, sino de guiar a los usuarios a crear *buenas preguntas*, eso es más importante. Por cierto que también creo que lo contrario igualmente se verifica en la mayoría de los casos (verificable mediante observación): las malas preguntas atraen malas respuestas.

> 5. ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?

Mi visión que dentro de un año **SOes será una comunidad más madura, donde los usuarios expertos y entusiastas de forma generosa seguirán creando esta base de conocimientos**, con el propósito tal vez optimista, de reducir la brecha tecnológica que existe en nuestros países. En nuestro idioma, con la misma calidad que en el sitio en inglés, pero con la calidez del idioma que nos une y nos acerca. Me gustaría contribuir a lograr esa visión como moderador.

> 6. Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?

Concibo *la calidad del sitio* como el binomio pregunta-respuesta y **creo que esas preguntas básicas deben ser respondidas en SOes**. Trataré de explicarme:  este sitio tiene un excelente posicionamiento en los buscadores, esas preguntas deben ser la carta de presentación del sitio para los visitantes. Que sea SOes la primera respuesta de Google hará que tengamos más visitantes (le conviene a la empresa) la calidad del sitio los convertirá en usuarios (nos conviene a todos).

> 7. Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?

Creo que la teoría de la moderación es una de las más grandes fortalezas de esta comunidad. Me gustaría trabajar para **mejorar nuestra capacidad para evaluar las preguntas**, pienso hacerlo con publicaciones en Meta que funcionen como talleres, exponiendo casos que nos ayuden a mejorar los criterios de moderación (y por qué no, a unificarlos).  Cierto es que no necesito superpoderes para hacerlo.

> 8. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

De entrada, me sienta mal, porque mis decisiones son guiadas por las mejores intenciones. Sin embargo, no creo que el escrutinio se deba tratar de dar explicaciones, **lo que ofrezco es transparencia y rendición de cuentas**, propongo informar de forma trimestral sobre las actividades que realice como moderador.

> 9. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

En este orden: a los otros moderadores del sitio, a otros moderadores de la red (creo que hay un chat para ellos), al gerente de la comunidad.

> 10. Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

Vuelvo a mi opinión sobre el binomio pregunta-respuesta. Una pregunta que cae en este supuesto y no tiene respuestas no la conservaría. **No evalúo una pregunta por su potencial en el futuro de recibir alguna respuesta, sino por su capacidad actual y presente para resolver un problema** al OP y a los visitantes. Como visitante, no me sirve una pregunta que no tenga respuestas, por muy interesante que parezca.

Comment: #7 "*publicaciones en Meta que funcionen como talleres*" ¿Qué significa? ¿Podrías elaborar en qué se diferencian de las preguntas de discusión *normales*? ¿Tenés algún ejemplo que hayas publicado en Meta que funcione como taller?

Comment: #10 "*no me sirve una pregunta que no tenga respuestas*" ¿Significa que, como moderador, estarías más inclinado a eiminar preguntas por el hecho de que no tienen respuestas? ¿Podrías detallar cómo actuarías como moderador con preguntas que, aunque cumplan con las condiciones para el sitio, no tienen ninguna respuesta?

Comment: @Mariano, me refiero al punto #10: _“Como visitante, no me sirve una pregunta que no tenga respuestas, por muy interesante que parezca”_ es la cita completa y es lo que significa que pienso **como visitante**. Como usuario he tomado acciones en este sentido y se pueden ver en esta [publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1828/jornada-de-limpieza) y como moderador, revisaría cada caso particular, y **creo** que usaría ese mismo criterio.

Comment: @Mariano, me refiero a #7: Las discusiones que hemos visto sobre este tema, generalmente piden explicaciones después de que una decisión se tomó. Yo propongo algo mas: Se expone un caso, se argumenta a favor o en contra, se acuerda que el argumento con mayores votos sea el criterio que prevalezca en casos iguales o parecidos.

Answer (score 11):

[fredyfx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-87905)

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Vamos por partes, primero lo felicito, si anda con generando una ola de respuestas valiosas, reconocerlo ayudará a que continúe así. En segundo lugar depende, los factores a evaluar son: a) Saber si es consciente de sus acciones en referencia a las reglas del sitio. b) ¿Qué intenciones tiene? ¿Son buenas, malas? ¿Está en modo troll?. La comunicación es la clave así que conversar con los demás moderadores y ver qué hacer.

> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Es muy importante entender cuáles fueron los motivos, saber el criterio que siguió para tomar dicha decisión, luego compartir con mucho respeto que discrepo de su accionar, buscar y encontrar la manera de mantener un orden en el sitio y la armonía entre moderadores porque tenemos la misma finalidad, debemos entendernos y esforzarnos en mantener la misma “frecuencia” de moderación.

> 3. ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?

Pregunta sin esfuerzo por “intentar” responder = alto % de ser cerrada: comienzo colocando el enlace del tour del sitio para que editen su pregunta agregando los detalles y el código que ha intentado, dejo la pregunta abierta un máximo de 24 horas desde que la vi, y si el usuario sigue sin efectuar intento, procedo a cerrar.

Pregunta con esfuerzo por “intentar” responder = bajo %  de ser cerrada: aquí generalmente busco en la documentación y las corazonadas que tengo son plasmadas como comentarios o en algunos casos donde las pruebo en local, aporto con respuesta.

> 4. ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano o (2) Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad. ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?

Prefiero ser permisivo. Sí, tengo una alternativa a ese dilema: “C’est la vie”, comparte lo que sabes, todos nacemos y tenemos la facultad de aprender, así que paciencia para enseñar cómo se debe preguntar, cosas que se deben decir para aumentar la calidad siempre van a estar.

> 5. ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?

Que sea uno de los lugares donde la gente entre sin miedo a preguntar, sin ser juzgados de “n00bs”, un lugar libre de estereotipos de “coders”, libre de elitismos. ¿Qué sería de esta industria si nadie hubiera compartido publicaciones “gratis” por la red? ¿Cuántas horas perderíamos buscando ese punto y coma faltante? Veo un lugar donde todos tengan el mismo derecho de aprender y crecer profesionalmente, una hermandad, un lugar fresh con gente que se puede desarrollar amistad y llevarse como hermanos, saber que la unión hace la fuerza y más aún en la industria donde estamos, saber llegar a StackOverflow y crecer entre todos

> 6. Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet. ¿Hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?

No, la principal razón es que no todos poseen la misma brújula para buscar por la red, y si hay alguna pregunta básica, hay usuarios que recién están iniciando en la programación y ¡van a tener muchísima alegría de poder responderla!

> 7. Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?

Spam y/o comentarios ofensivos, aquí entro en modo Kira (referencia a persona del anime: Death Note) y eliminar spam y/o comentario ofensivo. Si hay discusión, busco  y encuentro el balance de alguna u otra manera.

> 8. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

Me siento bien, la comunidad es libre, todos tenemos el mismo nivel, somos una hermandad y las cosas claras. Entre todos sabemos y entre todos apoyamos: me ha pasado explicar los motivos de cierres y en algunas ocasiones he tenido que re-abrir preguntas porque alguien sabía la respuesta a algo que pensé que era demasiado amplio como una pregunta sobre punteros en C++ Esto ha generado que más usuarios sientan que tienen el poder del cambio y de la mejora en el sitio, que realmente son escuchados y con ello: mayor número de personas que revisan y reportan y todos felices :D

> 9. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber cómo responder a la situación?

A los moderadores que tienen mayor cantidad de experiencia y en caso todo seamos nuevos, preguntar a los demás moderadores de la red de StackOverflow.

> 10. Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

Preguntas eliminadas son aquellas que habiendo solicitado mayores detalles en los comentarios: Carecen de esfuerzo de “intento” de solucionar y/o piden resolución de exámenes, tareas, prácticas del instituto o universidad.

Preguntas conservadas son aquellas que demuestran un intento en querer resolver, que se nota que han tratado y han explicado a detalle su razonamiento.

Comment: Creo que es el único grupo de respuestas razonablemente honestas, o razonables el resto de cosa solo sentí respuestas de como verme genial respondiendo esto. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano :) aprecio tu comentario :D saludos

Answer (score 9):

[ArtEze](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-87661)

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Lo que haría es atender esos reportes, y avisarle al usuario que puede ser suspendido si sigue con ese comportamiento.

> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Si considero que es necesario, discutirlo con el otro moderador para llegar a un acuerdo. De otro modo, si yo recupero la pregunta y él vuelve a borrarla, lo mejor es no insistir (en especial si es su propia pregunta).

> 3. ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?

Pienso que no es necesario conocer la temática para cerrar, editar o eliminar la pregunta. Por ejemplo, si está en inglés, no necesito conocer *C#* para cerrarla. Suelo intentar comprender el significado de la pregunta, ver si se puede mejorar el título, redactar mejor el problema.

> 4. ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano o (2) Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad. ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?

Prefiero la segunda opción. Ser estricto y cerrar la pregunta. El usuario tiene que darse cuenta y añadir mejoras, para poder abrirla nuevamente.

> 5. ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?

El sitio es inclusivo, te deja participar casi con total libertad, sería una lástima perder todos esos esfuerzos y soluciones que deja la gente. Le veo un gran futuro a este sitio realmente, en donde los usuarios no se faltan el respeto mutuamente y colaboran con armonía (nada de agarrarse a las piñas ni actitudes indignantes).

> 6. Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?

Dependiendo el caso, puede ser bueno o malo. En algunos casos, aporta mucho al sitio, ya que los usuarios pueden encontrar una solución más ingeniosa a un problema que se da por sentado.

> 7. Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?

No es un problema del sitio, es un deseo personal, o más bien, un problema que tengo con el sitio, y no creo que a la comunidad le importe. Había una pregunta, *Consulta sobre desarrollar una IA (inteligencia artificial)*. Usaría mis superpoderes para que no esté eliminada. Es una pregunta que yo quisiera que quede como recuerdo. Me gustó la pregunta, le di recompensas, y no me gustó que la eliminen.

Otro ejemplo que votaría para recuperar, que también le di recompensas, hice todo lo posible para que quede bien y lamentablemente la borraron: *Operaciones matemáticas en Java*.

El motivo por el que no las recupero yo mismo es que las volverían a borrar.

> 8. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

Me gusta escuchar a la gente, trato de atender a los problemas cuando sea posible. Que si es plagio o no, que si es duplicada en sentido opuesto. Todos esos debates finalmente tienen la solución correcta.

> 9. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

Planteo el problema en *Meta*, lo pregunto en el chat, o en algunos casos, lo hablo con *Juan M*.

> 10. Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

Muchos de esos reportes no son correctos. En vez de *"baja calidad"*, tendrían que reportarlo como *"no es una respuesta"*. En esos casos, eliminar la respuesta porque no valen ni como comentario. Son esas típicas respuestas que dicen, *"a mí me pasa lo mismo, por favor, ayuda"*.

También hay preguntas que son válidas y creo oportuno mejorarlas, pero tiene que ser un problema reproducible y solucionable. De ser una respuesta efectivamente de baja calidad, pero que sea una respuesta, si no se puede mejorar, doy voto negativo y marco el reporte como útil.

Las respuestas que generalmente son solo un enlace, y en ese caso no me queda otra alternativa que eliminarlas. Las que no son una respuesta hablan de todo menos de la pregunta, y no intentan resolver el problema. De lo contrario, son respuestas válidas.

Por ahora no recuerdo casos en los que se me complique mucho decidir si debo eliminarla.

Comment: La pregunta #1, creo que no es "que ese usuario genera reportes", sino que "se generan muchos reportes sobre comentarios de ese usuario"... Es decir, un usuario que entra en peleas habitualmente

Comment: En la pregunta #7, hablás de una pregunta (que recuerdo perfectamente), pero no estás describiendo el problema, y no sé si puede quedar claro... ¿Cuál es el problema con esa pregunta? ¿Por qué crees que es un problema de la comunidad? Además de recuperarla (que siendo moderador, no entiendo por qué lo planteas si fueses elegido), ¿qué otro tipo de contenido estarías recuperando y por qué?

Comment: En la pregunta #10 estás diciendo "*De ser una respuesta efectivamente de baja calidad, pero que sea una respuesta*"... No me queda del todo claro tu concepto. ¿Podrías definir con tus palabras qué es "baja calidad" y qué es "una respuesta"? ¿Cuáles son los casos complicados en los que optás por eliminar o mantener?

Comment: @Mariano Gracias por los comentarios, ya edité la respuesta.

Comment: Para quienes no tengan acceso a ver la pregunta de IA, esta es una publicación en Meta sobre esa pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1055/127

Comment: Primero te nominaste, luego te retiraste y ahora te retractaste y vuelves a estar en carrera. Pregunta: ¿Tu nominación es real? No pareces darle mucha seriedad al asunto ya que en el chat mencionaste que solo te retirabas para saber que pasaba, pensando que la elección comenzaría inmediatamente sin tí. Pero ya que no pasó nada decides volver entonces la pregunta es, ¿realmente deseas continuar con el cargo de moderador? O en caso de ganar luego sin previo aviso y sin razones claras decidirás retirarte?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz creo que es más que eso, en el chat no es que se haya retirado para ver qué pasaba, según su comentario en el chat se postuló para ver qué pasaba...lo que para mí es peor

Comment: Detrás de esta actitud de jugar a ser moderador no hay salud y menos con los hechos de los últimos días. Nominación lamentable, moderación que pasa sin pena ni gloria

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Mi postulación es real, deseo seguir siendo moderador, no me voy a retirar. Me había retirado para darle la oportunidad a otros a estar en la segunda vuelta, pero no sabía cómo funcionaban las elecciones.

Comment: Afortunadamente

Answer (score 9):

#### [Carlos Muñoz Rodriguez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/20/carlos-mu%C3%B1oz)

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

El ser un usuario activo y que produce muy buenas respuestas demuestra su interés y compromiso con el sitio. No es un usuario usuario cualquiera al que se puede desechar. Lo primero sería contactarlo, comunicarle el problema que tienen muchos usuarios con su interacción en el sitio y lo negativo de su conducta y darle la oportunidad que asimile que tiene la opción de cambiar e impactar de forma positiva no solo con sus respuestas sino con su trato cordial hacia los demás. De no ser el caso y de reiterar en su comportamiento negativo procedería a aplicar las sanciones correspondientes

> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Hablar así de simple, comunicarle mi desacuerdo al otro mopderador. Tal vez hay un punto de vista que el o ella no ha considerado hasta el momento y puedo hacerle cambiar de opinión. O tal vez existe un punto de vista que yo no he considerado y al conversar con el otro moderador entender el motivo de su cierra. De todas maneras lo que un moderador haya considerado será respetado por mi persona.

> 3. ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?

La moderación no requiere un excelente conocimiento sobre el tema en particular. Para eso están los usuarios. Existen cierto problemas como no esta claro cual es la pregunta que sin embargo un usuario experto podría haber entendido y respondido correctamente. Otras veces basta con buscar en Google algo sobre el tema y tener mejor claridad sobre el asunto. Lo más importante es dejarle a los usuario expertos que opinen sobre las preguntas mediante los votos y comentarios y estar atento a los reportes y colas de edición.

> 4. ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano o (2) Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad. ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?

Como mencioné en mi post de postulación tengo una fuerte inclinación hacía lal segunda alternativa. He expresado esta opinión varias veces en el meta, chat incluso en el webcast. Pero lo repito una vez más.

Es muy importante para asegurar el crecimeinto del sitio contar con preguntas y respuestas de calidad para poder atraer a más usuarios expertos.

Si un usuario nuevo no sigue las reglas y recomendaciones del sitio, se le debe invitar a revisarlas y hacer lo correcto que es cerrar las preguntas hasta que ellos puedan mejorar su preguntas. Si el usuario luego no lo hace está demostrando que solo vino al sitio a resolver su pregunta en particular y no piensa interactuar más. Tal vez ya resolvió su pregunta y nunca volverá, ni para marcar una respuesta como aceptada. Si la pregunta no tiene los mínimos estándares de calidad no le servirá a los expertos ni a futuros usuario que lleguen al sitio con el mismo problema.

Siempre es mejor dejar ir a un usuario que no aporta positivamente al sitio, que llenarse de preguntas la formuladas y con pocas respuestas que solo aumentan la carga a los editores y moderadores.

> 5. ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?

Mi objetivo número 1 es aumentar la calidad del sitio. Mi visión es que el sitio suba su porcentaje de preguntas respondidas y el ratio de respuestas sobre preguntas que fue el [principal problema durante la fase beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) Obviamente yo mismo no puedo lograrlo resolviendo miles de preguntas sino que pienso que esto se puede lograr atrayendo mas expertos que esten dispuestos a dar su tiempo en lograr hacer que este sitio esté a la par con el sitio en inglés. Los que hayan hecho alguna pregunta en el sitio en  en inglés conocen la sensación de ver como es respondida prácticamente en segundos por varias personas, muchas veces isn saber a cual darle la respuesta aceptada. Esa es mi visión del sitio, que se logre exactamente esa sensación en el sitio en español. Y solo se puede lograr con dos cosas.

Por un lado, preguntas de usuarios nuevos de calidad de tal maneras que puedan ser respondidas rápidamente por los expertos. Esto se logra mediante respuestas rápidas a ediciones y votos de cierre, y comentarios para ayudar al usuario nuevo a formular excelentes preguntas.

Por otro lado atrayendo a expertos al demostrarles que los contenidos en SO en español son relevantes e interesantes que motiven su pàrticipación.

> 6. Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?

No hacen bajar la calidad del sitio si es que la pregunta en sí misma ha sido formulado correctamente y es objetiva. Muchas veces la solución efectivamente esta al alcance de una simple búsqueda, sin embargo muchas veces las mejores respuestas estarán en el sitio en inglés, lengua que no todos manejan por lo que es importante que esta base de preguntas comunes y sencillas también se encuentres resueltas en nuestro sitio.

> 7. Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?

A veces la demora en los cierres de preguntas evidentemente mal formuladas hace que aparezcan demasiado tiempo en el sitio lo cual puede hacer parecer a los nuevos usuario que está bien que existan y que proliferen en el sitio. Al tener la oportunidad de cerrar las preguntas sin más votos puede ayudar a disminuir este tiempo de espera.

> 8. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

Un reto y una oportunidad de mejorar mi comunicación y poder sustentar con buenos motivos las acciones y decisiones que haga en el sitio. Es una gran oportunidad de crecimeinto profesional

> 9. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

Lo primero es el sentido común, hay cosas que pueden no estar especificadas en el sitio pero que son de obvia aplicación como ciertos comportamientos que puedan haber que no esten marcados explicitamente como negativos pero que generen un malestar en la comunidad.

Lo siguiente es el Meta. El meta es una poderosa herramienta de comunicación y decisión que permite que varias cabezas opinen o decidan sobre un problema en la comunidad. Mientras mas opiniones hayan mejor preparado se podrá estar para resolver los problemas.

Finalmente tenemos el chat donde están algunos de los usuarios mas activos e involucrados con el sitio donde se puede siempre tener la confianza de tocar los temas de una forma más rápida y con mayor calidez que un post, muchas veces algunos problemas donde la gente parece discutir en los comentarios se solucionan muy fácilmente en el chat donde ambas partes pueden darse cuenta y explicar sus puntos de vista y resolver malentendidos

> 10. Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

La ayuda establece claramente cuales son las [preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) y [respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) que deben ser eliminadas.

Básicamente se puede resumir en:

- Preguntas insalvables donde por ejemplo no hay interés del usuario en mejorarlas o editarlas, no son preguntas realmente, es spam, o contiene lenguaje o expresiones inadecuadas debn ser eliminadas.
- Preguntas que pueden y deben ser mejoradas son candidatas a ser cerradas.

Comment: Hola Carlos, creo que la pregunta 10 la evade remitiendo a los enlaces que  proporciona, cuando se solicita hacerlo en sus propias palabras

Comment: Hola dwarandae, abajo de los links está el resumen. Mi postura es simple el límite esta ya definido, solo es cuestión de revisar los normas.

Comment: @Carlos coincido con dwarandae. Es decir, para poner un ejemplo, siguiendo tu lógica, esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6691 "*es spam, o contiene lenguaje o expresiones inadecuadas"*?

Comment: @Mariano el pequeño resumen que he colocado se refiera a preguntas no a respuestas. En particular ese respuesta es más un comentario que una respuesta ya que el mismo usuario está pidiendo que se agregue más código lo cual significa que la pregunta aún no estaba apta para responder correctamente. – Carlos Muñoz hace 4 horas

Answer (score 7):

### [Ivan Botero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-87554)

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

*Primero, hacer que prevalezca tanto el respeto como la imparcialidad, no solo con él sino con cualquier usuario del sitio, bien este es un valor importante a mantener con cualquier persona. Respecto al hecho consideraría evaluar el contenido de sus reportes/comentarios, quiero decir, si los hace de una manera ofensiva o bien los hace para aclarar detalles en sus respuestas y comunicaría al usuario lo que encuentre respecto a su comportamiento de modo que este no continúe con este tipo de comportamientos que puedan ir contra los principios de la comunidad.*

> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

*Considero que lo primero a hacer seria, contactar con el moderador en cuestión, para en dicho caso, discutir la razón por la cual llevo a cabo dicha acción, al debatir podría llevar a una conclusión que cierre/reabra la pregunta, mas en un caso que no se llegue a una conclusión, considero que lo mas correcto es con otro moderador, para que en dicho caso, se tome en cuenta su opinión y así determinar si es o no correcto el cierre/eliminación de dicha pregunta.*

> 3. ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?

*Creo que lo mas conveniente en un caso de estos podría ser, primero, determinar el posible problema en la pregunta, a continuación, contactar con alguno de los moderadores del equipo que tenga conocimientos en dicha tecnología y discutir con el los argumentos que se tengan acerca del contenido de la pregunta, en un caso que ninguno tuviese conocimiento de la tecnología en cuestión, considero que lo mas conveniente es basarse en lo mas fundamental para el contenido de la pregunta, quiero decir, valorar en ella todos los elementos que consideramos elementales en una pregunta (Ejemplo Mínimo, Pregunta Clara, Intento por parte del usuario).*

> 4. ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano o (2) Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad. ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?

*En mi opinión, lo primero sera siempre advertir a aquellos usuarios nuevos, acerca del funcionamiento del sitio (Como preguntar, Recorrido, Ejemplo Mínimo), para que este lo tenga en cuenta, después de ello considero prudente dar un **"tiempo de gracia"** *(el cual a mi consideración debe ser de entre 1 a 2 horas)*, para llamar la atención del usuario sin ser tan estricto, y si el usuario no responde después de dicho tiempo, creo que es prudente llevar a cabo la puesta en espera de una pregunta, pero lo mas importante es, en mi opinión, no ser tan estricto si el usuario acaba de registrarse y no entiende como funciona el sitio, esto podría hacer que el usuario "tema" a la hora de preguntar, y que posteriormente prefiera buscar en otro lugar, lo mas importante es enseñar a los nuevos usuarios las características de nuestro sitio.*

> 5. ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?

*Quisiera ver al sitio con aun mas afluencia de gente, que este sitio y nuestra comunidad sea reconocida como una fuente de conocimiento a nivel general, sé que no podría decir que seremos tal cual como lo es SOen en poco tiempo, pero quisiera que todo aquello que respondemos/preguntemos sirva a muchos usuarios en el futuro en su propio idioma.*

> 6. Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?

*En mi opinión, NO. Porque? Porque cualquier información por muy básica que sea no deja de ser información, siempre podrá ser mejorada, siempre se podrá dar de mas, quiero decir, si un usuario busca algo muy elemental que pueda ser resuelto con un buscador, y alguien le responde, otro usuario podría complementar dicha información con algo que aprendió por experiencia y otro complementar con algo mas esto hace información de calidad.*

> 7. Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?

*Uno de los problemas que considero que podría tratarse, seria el trato de muchos de nuestros nuevos usuarios, en mi opinión, muchos usuarios quizá llegan con una idea errónea del funcionamiento del sitio y en muchas ocasiones pueden crear publicaciones consideradas como de baja calidad sin siquiera pensarlo. En conclusión, trabajar para mantener las publicaciones de calidad en el sitio.*

> 8. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

*Considero que la labor de un moderador debe ser allí, frente a la comunidad, en el chat, en el sitio Meta, y esta labor debe de ser constante. Por lo cual, ha de ser normal que sea escudriñado a menudo, por lo que haga, pero, si es por el bien y la mejora del sitio, considero que es uno de los gajes del oficio.*

> 9. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

*Lo primero seria considerar a mi nivel personal y tener argumentos acerca de lo que creo que se debería hacer respecto a dicha situación, a continuación discutiría en primer lugar con los otros moderadores del equipo para tomar una decisión, y en un caso que se considere necesario, contactaría con Juan M para tomar una decisión al respecto.*

> 10. Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

*Creo que la mejor manera de definir un limite entre las preguntas de dicho tipo debería basarse en la información que se pueda encontrar en sus respuestas, me refiero, si tenemos una pregunta que por X razón ha sido marcada de baja calidad, por falta de información, pero entre sus respuestas algunos de los usuarios respondieron de una manera clara, especifica, considero que así se podría determinar si se conserva una pregunta, puede ser que la pregunta sea de baja calidad por algún motivo, pero eso no necesariamente baja la calidad de las respuestas, que de alguno u otro modo sean concretas con la solución y que en un futuro puedan servir a usuarios con problemas similares.*

Comment: Mencionas un "tiempo de gracia" pero no dices cuál es el plazo del mismo. ¿Sería una horas, días? ¿Cuántos?

Comment: Mi tiempo de gracia es de una hora y, en general la respuesta a la pregunta #7 es la que mas me ha gustado ya que lo considero muy importante para **educar a los usuarios**.

Comment: @Rubén Considero prudente entre 1 a 2 horas, asi damos tiempo al usuario para corregir lo que le falte a su publicacion, gracias por tu comentario

Answer (score 0):

#### [Paul Vargas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-87652)

> <sup>1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?</sup>

¡Compañeros y compañeras!, lo primero que debe estar presente es el diálogo. ¡Eso es lo que debe imperar! Pudiera ser que nuestro camarada, en el afán de querer brindar un valiosísimo servicio al sitio, encontrase que cierto comentario no debería estar donde está, clave una bandera de alerta, y nosotros, como ◇moderadores, corremos tan rápido como podemos a ver qué está pasando ahí, y luego, después de echar un vistazo, consideremos que no es un reporte útil y lo rechazamos tan fehacientemente porque somos seguidores estrictos de las reglas que se han definido y nuestro tiempo disponible, muy precioso.

Yo trataría en la mayor medida de lo posible de contactar a dicho usuario (ya en este momento debe sentirse desconcertado por tanto reporte repelido) y explicarle cómo usar los susodichos reportes y el sistema correctamente para evitar, sobretodo (y lo más importante), que sea automáticamente *baneado* cuando se llega a los números críticos de reportes rechazados durante la semana o días previos.

> <sup>2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?</sup>

De la misma manera, querido amigo, aquí lo importante es la comunicación. Lo primero que haría es contactar a mi compañero ◇moderador y preguntarle amablemente (¡Por su puesto que también le ofrecería una ración de cafeína ☕☕☕ de mi preciada reserva personal!) las razones por las cuales se vió *orillado* a tal punto de cerrar/eliminar/etc tal pregunta. Importante conocer sus razones. Porque pudiera darse el caso en que mis propias razones para mantener la pregunta abierta estén por completo equivocadas.

No obstante, queridos amigos, si después de un análisis concienzudo de sus razones y motivos, yo sigo creyendo firmemente que la pregunta no merecía ser cerrada/eliminada/etc, debo sustentar mi posición con rigurosas referencias específicas a la documentación, a las páginas de ayuda, a los *metas* relacionados (incluso metas de otros *planetas*, *Err*... perdón, quise decir de otros sitios), y mostrárselos a mi colega ◇moderador. Tengo plena confianza en que llegaremos a un consenso. Naturalmente que la pregunta no puede ser revivida sin antes establecer esta obligatoria charla y haber llegado a tal conclusión.

> <sup>3. ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?</sup>

*Mira*, amigo, toda pregunta debe cumplir con ciertos requisitos básicos (enumerados en [*¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [*Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) y si la pregunta no los cumple, pues... todos sabemos que la comunidad comenzará a actuar rápidamente para cerrar la pregunta. Nuestra cometido, en este caso, es apresurar ese proceso.

Sin embargo, si la pregunta aparentemente cumple con todos los requisitos y sí, efectivamente es una tecnología desconocida para mí, lo mejor que podría uno hacer es levantar la mano y preguntar, ya sea a los usuarios en el *chat* o a los compañeros ◇moderadores, si se trata de una pregunta sensata. Es preferible tomar una decisión de manera informada que una decisión que cae por  el agujero de la madriguera.

> <sup>4. ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano o (2) Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad. ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?</sup>

Camarada... amigo... todo mundo sabe, aunque nadie lo dice abiertamente, que lo mejor para el negocio (Stack Exchange Inc) es que haya más usuarios, ¿cierto? ¿estás conmigo? ¡Es la verdad! Yo te lo digo. Ahora, mi *trabajo* como ◇moderador es buscar en la mayor medida de lo posible retener al usuario... y si debo dedicar un tiempo especial para enseñarle como funciona el sitio, lo haré.

Y si a pesar de todos los esfuerzos... y si a pesar de todas las horas dedicadas ⏰... y si a pesar de todos los intentos hechos con todo lo que se tiene al alcance... no hay un resultado positivo, entonces se procede a eliminar el contenido “indeseado”.  ¡Por el bien del sitio! ¡Por el bien de la comunidad! ¡Ea! ¡Viva! ... Perdón, me emocioné.

> <sup>5. ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?</sup>

Mi visión ...  ... es que el sitio tendrá contenido de muy alta calidad y será conocido todavía todavía más en todo el orbe donde se habla español, porque donde haya un programador, es muy probable que ahí esté un navegador con un favorito marcadamente visible:
[**`★ https://es.stackoverflow.com/`**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

> <sup>6. Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?</sup>

¡De ninguna manera! Pero, ¡qué pregunta! De hecho, pudiera darse el caso en que la pregunta "básica" tenga en el sitio una respuesta de altisísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísísíma calidad, incluso superior a las referencias confiables y verificables, del grado de una tesis doctoral.

> <sup>7. Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?</sup>

Creo, camaradas, que uno los problemas más grandes que existen en el sitio son las preguntas y respuestas de muy baja calidad. En el caso de las preguntas, entran en las categorías enumeradas en [*¿Que tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) y en el caso de las respuestas no consideran [*¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Mi labor será acelerar el proceso de **`eliminación`**  una vez que haya pasado un tiempo más o menos razonable para que el *OP* hubiese hecho un edición aceptable de la pregunta o respuesta.

> <sup>8. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?</sup>

Querido camarada, es más que claro que los ◇moderadores están más expuestos al escrutinio y crítica por parte de los usuarios, los cuales tienen un interés legítimo en conocer los porqués de cierta acción tomada.

En realidad, no tengo ningún problema con eso. Como había dicho previamente: “Toda crítica, opinión, petición, reclamo y sugerencia es absolutamente bienvenida.” Si debo exponer el proceso completo y detallado que me llevó a tomar tal decisión, lo haré sin temor ni temblor. Soy alguien excesivamente metódico y no tomo una decisión sin antes haber analizado *todas* las variables involucradas.

> <sup>9. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?</sup>

Camaradas, estamos en una *comunidad*. Y como comunidad que somos, tenemos a muchas personas a quienes podemos pedir ayuda: usuarios, ◇moderadores o *community managers*. Creo que todos en conjunto podemos tomar la mejor decisión, buscando proteger

Y una vez resuelto el problema, documentar el proceso en las páginas de ayuda o en algún meta por si se presenta un evento así en el futuro.

> <sup>10. Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?</sup>

¿Definir `"el límite"`? ¿Por qué limitarnos, compañeros y compañeras?

- Si una pregunta/respuesta que debe ser eliminada, se elimina.
- Si una pregunta/respuesta puede ser rescatada, se conserva.

Comment: Pienso que seria bueno que constestaras de una manera impersonal, ya que no hay nadie que te este haciendo las preguntas directamente, sino fue la comunidad quien las planteo. Me parecio muy poco serio la exageración de la respuesta en la pregunta 6. Como una mera sugerencia, evitar el abuso de los tres puntos "...".

Comment: Paul: Me da gusto que te animaras a participar. Aunque tiene algunos votos negativos (-6) también un número similar de  positivos(+5). El cuestionario sobresale, entiendo que con toda intensión, tanto por el modo personal y el uso de emoticonos así como por la crítica implícita al sistema y a la comunidad misma,  sin embargo, considero que de aquí se pueden derivar varias reflexiones que deriven al fortalecimiento de la comunidad.

Comment: Hablas de la importancia del diálogo y la comunicación, cosa que está muy bien para un moderador pero veo en tu postulación que no has contestado a nadie en los comentarios. A lo único que has respondido ha sido con una evasiva para no decir nada al final. El resto de candidatos han entrado en el debate, han contestado las preguntas o comentado las observaciones que les han hecho los usuarios. ¿Por qué debo creer que si eres moderador la comunicación será primordial para ti?

Comment: Me incomoda tanta informalidad en las respuestas

Answer (score -2):

[**Joel Ibaceta**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-87558)

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de
>      argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Un reporte con argumentos es valido, todo tiene que estar siempre bajo un criterio mínimo de sentido común, las respuestas valiosas son bienvenidas, pero eso no significa un diferencial para el usuario sobre como deberíamos actuar frente a malas practicas.

> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Como en cualquier situación cotidiana en la que una persona toma una decisión que a uno le parece equivocada es cuestión de entender sus motivos, quizás puede tener mas información o un criterio valido distinto para ello, evitaría los comentarios públicos de todos modos, el dialogo es importante creo que es una de las ventajas de contar con mas de un moderador, inteligencia colectiva.

> 3. ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?

Al no contar con en expertise adecuado para hacer un juicio de opinión sobre la calidad del contenido, únicamente podría prevenir las malas practicas generales para las preguntas del sitio, en caso algún moderador con mayor expertise  sobre el tema no pueda atender la pregunta con anterioridad, tendría que tratar de entender si la pregunta es una pregunta técnica y puede tener una respuesta valida, no hay nada peor que hacer un juicio sin tener suficiente información para estar seguro de las decisiones que se toman.

> 4. ¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad? Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres: (1) Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano (2) Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad. ¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este "dilema"?

Personalmente bajo un rol de moderador considero que la retención de usuarios no corresponde a una responsabilidad directa, lo que si se debe evitar es incidir de manera premeditada a generar perdida de usuarios, la permisividad o el ser demasiado estricto son 2 extremos no aceptables, creo que como toda comunidad pasa por etapas en las que los criterios deben ser discutibles y deben contribuir a mejorar la calidad del contenido generado sin crear barreras de entrada innecesarias, como todo deben pasar por un proceso de mejora continua y flexibilidad.

> 5. ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?

Como en la mayoría de etapas en la vida, después de asumir un rol de responsabilidad luego te toca pasar a ser un espectador y dejar que la nueva generación pueda tener la libertad de tomar las riendas, pero es importante también que se tomen en cuenta los aprendizajes del pasado para no repetir errores de gestiones anteriores.

Personalmente me gustaría que los ciclos sean bajo una mentalidad de mejora continua, que mañana seamos mejor que hoy y hoy estemos trabajando para hacer mejor las cosas que ayer, no tiene mucho sentido solo seguir las reglas y esperar que todo salga bien.

> 6. Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?

No necesariamente, ya que muchas de estas "primeras búsquedas" suelen ser referencias a stackoverflow, por lo que generar contenido "básico" permite evitar repetir las preguntas y generar contenido útil para usuarios nuevos, creo que es mejor reportarla como duplicada y darle una respuesta que cerrar mas preguntas.

> 7. Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?

Creo que es importante tener en cuenta las diferencias culturales, tecnológicas y de lenguaje, que existen en el español y los países de la región, para poder tener criterios mas abiertos de moderación, no existe la verdad absoluta y muchas veces es importante pensar un poco fuera de nuestro circulo para poder tomar decisiones mas acertadas.

Vi que hay mucha critica sobre la calidad de las preguntas, es un fenómeno mas cultural que del sitio, la cultura del copy&paste y de los tutoriales paso a paso desde 0, generan en latino américa, en lugar de nadar contra la corriente, creo que es mejor usar la corriente para generar energía, generar contenido “básico”, indexarlo evita el mar de preguntas “básicas” que quieren evitar y sirve como manual de cabecera a todo este gran porcentaje de programadores jóvenes latinoamericanos que buscan resultados rápidos con mínimo esfuerzo, todo esto se prestaría a una larga discusión pero creo que Meta seria un mejor lugar.

> 8. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

Después de experiencias con prensa, creo que uno de las primeras habilidades que alguien que aspira a un cargo de responsabilidad  es poder estar abierto a la critica y acostumbrarse a los cuestionamientos, a veces es necesario que exista alguien con suficiente valentía de tomar decisiones donde nadie mas lo hace.

> 9. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

Lo ideal seria escuchar a los demás y aprender de experiencias pasadas, no siempre seguir las “normas” al pie de la letra es el mejor camino, recordemos que nuestros países siguen el criterio de jurisprudencia, me parece que hasta el momentos nos ha funcionado bastante bien, por lo que no creo que sea tan descabellado tomar referencias del pasado para poder aprender de ello y resolver los casos nuevos.

> 10. Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

Trataría de reducir el mínimo de preguntas eliminadas, uno de los problemas que genera una "mala" pregunta eliminada es dejar abierta la posibilidad a que aparezca otra igual, veo mucho publico nuevo en SOes no podemos asumir que nuestras acciones de hace 5 meses tengan efecto en estos nuevos usuarios activos, el publico se renueva y muchas veces debemos empezar un ciclo nuevamente.

Comment: Gracias por responder, Joel. Respecto *¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?*, entiendo que se refiere a qué objetivos personales te pones en cuanto a cosas que tú como moderador querrías cambiar. El cargo en principio es vitalicio.

Comment: En principio se esperaria que si, igual todo tiene un ciclo, es iluso hacer planes hacia el infinito, tratare de ampliar tomando tu comentario.

Comment: Me parece particular que hasta el momento sea el candidato con la peor votación, ¿a qué cree que se debe?

Por otro lado, ¿no es mejor educar a los nuevos usuarios en vez de tener miedo de eliminar preguntas de baja calidad?

Comment: @dwarandae yo no le llamaría miedo y "educar" es una palabra muy genérica cuando hablas de un publico sobre el cual no tienes control, yo creo que es cuestión de encausar las dudas, en lugar de crear barreras de entrada, seria una larga discusión, quizás podamos tenerla en chat o meta.

Comment: @JoelIbaceta sacaré tiempo para tenerla en el chat luego

Comment: #6 "*es mejor reportarla como duplicada*" ... Siendo moderador, ¿A quién la reportarías?