# ¿Por qué mi respuesta ha sido eliminada pero colocada como comentario?

Tags: soporte, respuesta, moderación, eliminación-de-respuestas, respuestas-a-comentarios

Me acabo de dar cuenta de que una de mis [respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119940/vmware-fusion-u-otros-consumo-de-ram/119942#119942) ha sido suprimida. Entiendo que puede ser por mal contenido, etc, pero lo curioso es que ha sido colocada como comentario.

Me da curiosidad saber: ¿Cuál es el criterio para pasar una respuesta a comentarios? ¿Si la respuesta ha sido votada positivamente también ha de aplicarse?

Entiendo que una respuesta que no responde, no lo es. ¿Pero si responde, cuál es el limite entre respuesta y comentario?

No había visto ningun caso hasta ahora, y estaría bien para que no me vuelva a suceder y/o poder moderar a otros usuarios.

Comment: Veremos si algun moderador te lo explica exactamente. Pero imagino que la pregunta ha sido reportada como _no es una respuesta_,pasando a la cola de revisión correspondiente, y una vez alli ha sido votada como _Esto es comentario sobre otra publicación, no una respuesta_, provocando que algun administrador la haya convertido en comentario.

Comment: ¿Pero entonces, cual es el criterio para decidir en que momento es una respuesta y en cual un comentario? ¿Donde esta el límite?

Comment: El criterio es el de las personas que votan para decidir si es o no una respuesta. Ahora mismo no se si son necesarios 5 votos como para cerrar una pregunta, intentaré informarme.

Comment: He remitido al moderador que hizo esta conversión, para que de su opinión del caso. Yo suelo pasar respuestas a comentarios cuando se ha *respondido* un comentario y se ve porque no tiene rep para comentar. Si la publicacion ya tiene votos positivos entonces le dejo un comentario diciendo que ha de mejorar la respuesta siguiendo [answer].  Un saludo

Answer (score -5):

Décima respuesta de JorgeSys a [2017 Elección de Moderador - Cuestionario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2537/301)

> X) Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como
>   muy baja calidad, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de
>   moderador (por ejemplo, las "revisiones de baja calidad disputadas").
>   ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las
>   preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?
>
> > Me preguntaría principalmente si son de utilidad para la comunidad
> >     para determinar conservarlas, algunas pueden incluso ser editadas para
> >     tener una calidad aceptable, si no llega a tener calidad simplemente
> >     se eliminaría.

Si bien en lo anterior se trata sobre preguntas es razonable pensar que el mismo criterio aplique a respuestas.

También es relevante la tercera respuesta:

> III) ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de
>   las que no tienes conocimientos?
>
> > La cantidad de tecnologías que abarca SO es extensa, es muy posible
> >     que algún moderador se encuentre situación, mi respuesta es que otro
> >     moderador con conocimiento tome la decisión o incluso documentarme
> >     sobre la tecnología para la toma de una decisión.

Habrá quien piense que un moderador diamantado debiera dejar que los usuarios con conocimientos de esa tecnología decidan qué hacer con esa respuesta. Que el moderador solo debe actuar respecto a spam, respuestas que no son respuestas o violaciones de los Términos de Servicio.

Pero JorgeSys fue elegido por una decisión mayoritaria de una comunidad que conocía esto antes de votar. Que un moderador diamantado use sus conocimientos técnicos sobre el tema tratado en una pregunta/respuesta a la hora de moderar fue aceptado por la comunidad. Está cumpliendo con aquello a lo que se comprometió públicamente.

Comment: Me parece que esto no está relacionado a la pregunta. El autor está preguntando cuál es el criterio para eliminar, y ambos sabemos que un moderador no lo define. Jorgesys no está en tela de juicio acá, y si hay acciones con las que no estás de acuerdo, creo que este no es el lugar. Además, convengamos que tuvo una respuesta inmediata dando sus motivos, por lo que agregar una respuesta así me parece poco constructivo.

Comment: @Mariano El criterio está justo al principio de la respuesta: "[...] **si no llega a tener calidad simplemente se eliminaría**."