# ¿Qué hacer si un moderador convierte a comentario una respuesta válida?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, moderación, moderadores

Recientemente un Moderador convirtió mi respuesta a comentario. Era una respuesta válida porque hacia referencia a la documentación oficial y adicionalmente dejaba un ejemplo.

Pero además de convertir mi respuesta en comentario, el Moderador agregó su propia respuesta (haciendo referencia al mismo enlace a la documentación oficial que yo había colocado)

**Edito: esto que agregué no me consta, cuando volví a entrar a SO, mi respuesta estaba como respuesta y no comentario**
*y luego que fue aceptada su respuesta, volvió a convertir en respuesta lo que había pasado a comentario.*

¿Es abuso de privilegio de ser moderador? Yo opté por votar negativamente su respuesta; pero no me parece justa la forma de actuar del Moderador ya que dediqué mi tiempo para responder y dedico tiempo al sitio.

Comment: Podrias indicarnos la respuesta asi podemos ver el historial? es muy raro lo que decis...

Comment: Igual, recuerda votar el contenido y no a la persona....

Comment: Hola, tu respuesta se regreso y esto que comentas no fue asi "y luego que fue aceptada su respuesta, volvió a convertir en respuesta lo que había pasado a comentario.", no levantes falsos testimonios por favor, **tu respuesta no era un comentario, el usuario simplemente decidio marcar como solucion la respuesta que el decidio,** agregar un enlace de la documentacion no indica que otra respuesta no lo pueda agregar, si dejaste una ejemplo es importante agregar lo esencial del enlace, revisa [answer]. Recuerda que el que responde no puede determinar que su respuesta debe ser marcada como valida.

Comment: Puedes ver la hora a la cual el OP agrego un comentario a ambas preguntas, de hecho comento primero tu pregunta. Recuerda tambien que es muy importante ayudar a los nuevos usuarios a mejorar sus preguntas.

Comment: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` que cosas.

Comment: @Jorgesys ¿tú convertiste su respuesta en comentario en algún momento? Segun el historial si lo hiciste, ¿cual fue el motivo de esa accion?

Comment: @Jorgesys cuando a una respuesta se puede mejorar o se debe mejorar, se le deja un comentario a quien responde para que mejore su respuesta (es lo que he visto). No entiendo porque la moviste a comentario, por lo que surge la misma duda que ¿cual fue el motivo de esa acción?

Comment: He realizado infinidad de publicaciones pero un usuario que tiene tiempo en el sitio debería conocer como responder de acuerdo a [answer], la publicación se restauro. El problema es que tu respuesta no fue aceptada?. Votar por venganza solo porque el OP selecciono mi respuesta como correcta fue motivo de voto negativo de tu parte? En estos casos realizas votos negativos a las respuestas de otros usuarios ? @CesarRomero

Comment: Creo que los moderadores, en este caso  @Jorgesys no debería intentar desviar el tema de la discusión. Bien o mal, la respuesta, ciertamente fue elegida, pero la pregunta fue ¿Por qué la acción? Pese a ello, sí, había varias cosas respecto a la respuesta del OP que podían ser mejoradas, pero por lo poco que he visto, justo eso se hace sobre la misma respuesta del usuario, no con lo realizado.

Comment: @ErickIO porque considere a primera instancia que era un comentario, posteriormente decidí regresar la publicación. La molestia de este usuario es que el no recibió la respuesta aceptada, incluso afirma que voto negativamente por venganza porque dice "dediqué mi tiempo para responder y dedico tiempo al sitio.", bueno tal vez yo no dedico tanto tiempo como él...

Comment: @Jorgesys aca no hay una competencia de tiempos dedicados al sitio..., aquí creo que basta con reconocer que te equivocaste(y pedir disculpas si es necesario) y que para las siguientes ocasiones vas a tomarte más tiempo en revisar tus acciones ya que tienen consecuencias en la dinámica del sitio, como se dice: "Más poder conlleva más responsabilidad"

Comment: @Jorgesys Como señal ErickIO y yo concuerdo el tema principal: La decision de convertir una respuesta a comentario. Obviamente no estamos de acuerdo con los votos negativos sin basarse en la publicación y no en la persona pero al fin y al cabo el voto es subjetivo, esas son las ventajas y desventajas de la democracia de los votos.

Comment: @eyllanesc dices " basta con reconocer que te equivocaste", pues así fue por eso regrese la pregunta, no estas leyendo?, sinceramente no entiendo cual es tu objetivo. Me dices "un falacia ad hominen", pregunto a que te refieres y no deseas responder. Ahora gracias a esta publicación estoy recibiendo votos negativos a mi respuesta.

Comment: No entiendo por qué nadie ha quitado el enlace a la pregunta. Fedorqui lo habría hecho ya porque termina un poco de gente dando votos negativos por algo que no tiene que ver con la pregunta ni con la respuesta. Además, no les quedan bien las acusaciones, que la rep no da millas ni les baja el saldo en la tarjeta de crédito. Presumamos la buena fe de las personas, que así funciona mejor SO

Comment: @Alfabravo no, yo no lo hubiera hecho y de hecho me sorprende que se haya eliminado. Una cosa es el [efecto meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4052/83), otra es la rendición de cuentas y para ello la transparencia es fundamental (máxime cuando el moderador no está dando los detalles sino liando el debate). En lo que sí estoy de acuerdo en que en este caso ha acabado habiendo un aluvión de votos (+ y -) en las publicaciones referenciadas que muy poco tienen que ver con la calidad.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo tampoco es la necesidad de mover respuestas a comentarios con tanta premura. Un moderador debe actuar si claramente no es una respuesta; en caso contrario, debe dejar a la comunidad que decida. Y si hay dudas y quiere acelerar el proceso, el moderador puede reportar la publicación como "baja calidad" para que entre en la cola de revisión y así asegurarse de que más gente lo valorará.

Comment: Entonces, que pasa? todo queda así y aquí no ha pasado nada?

Comment: Relacionado, otra cosa similar que pasó: [¿Por qué mi respuesta ha sido eliminada pero colocada como comentario?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2942/83)

Answer (score 16):

Más allá del hecho que el AP marque una u otra respuesta como aceptada, lo que no entiendo es porque el moderador diamantado convirtió una respuesta válida en comentario, quizás no sea la mejor respuesta pero para mi es una respuesta válida.

Según el historial se convirtió en comentario desde 5:18 hasta las 16:10, durante ese tiempo pudo recibir *feedback*, y pudo mejorar su respuesta, y no ser un simple comentario.

A mi tambien me parece un abuso de sus poderes, seria genial que el moderador explique los motivos de la conversión.

#### Actualizaciòn:

[Un comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4787/que-hacer-si-un-mod-convierte-a-comentario-una-respuesta-valida/4788?noredirect=1#comment19631_4788) del moderador diamantado es:

*La respuesta tiene enlaces, se convirtio a comentario pero posteriormente se regreso*, de lo que entiendo que cualquier post que tenga algún enlace entonces debe ser convertido a comentario, ¿esto es correcto? Yo pienso que esa acción es un abuso por lo que pediría a los moderadores diamantados que se tomen el tiempo para analizar que post se deben convertir en comentarios ya que la reversión de la acción demuestra que su acciòn fue incorrecta.

Comment: La respuesta tiene enlaces, se convirtio a comentario pero posteriormente se regreso, el usuario nunca realizo una edicion a su respuesta. 3 dias despues este usuario argumenta que cuando se hizo comentario su respuesta y por eso no aceptaron su respuesta, incluso realizo votacion negativa por venganza.

Comment: @Jorgesys 1) yo no discuto la votación, cada usuario puede votar como desee, esas son las reglas de SO por lo que mi post no se centra en ello y lo señale en la primera línea por lo que no nos distraigamos en eso por favor. 2) Que una respuesta tenga enlaces no implica que se deba convertir a comentario, yo he publicado muchas respuestas señalando: *Debes usar X* y al lado he colocado un enlace. Aun pienso que es un abuso

Comment: Tu eres el usuario que considera que la mayoria de las preguntas y respuestas son validas, https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4601/por-qu%c3%a9-algunos-revisores-de-esta-respuesta-se%c3%b1alan-que-no-es-una-respuesta/4605 es importante revisar revisar [ask] y [answer] porque tienes una idea muy diferente a lo que se define en el sitio.

Comment: Que es "un falacia ad hominen"? De que país eres?

Comment: @Jorgesys ¿qué  importancia tiene el país al que pertenezco? Mi punto es que no debiste volver a comentario una respuesta válida, es vàlida actualmente y como señalas nunca tuvo edición por lo que siempre fue válida.

Comment: Me podrías explicar que es "un falacia ad hominen"?. No debí por esa razón rectifique y se regreso como respuesta.

Comment: @Jorgesys no discutamos sobre temas irrelevantes que como ya te diste cuenta yo ya lo elimine, discutamos sobre el tema de fondo.

Comment: Quieres "discutir" pero no respondes, porque ahora eliminaste tu comentario? porque no responder a mi preguntas? a que te refieres con  "un falacia ad hominen"? @eyllanesc

Comment: @Jorgesys .... adios, el nivel de discusión se hizo monótono.... Siempre tengo la mayor admiración por los moderadores ya que son muy equilibrados en sus decisiones pero parece que no son asi todos,... bastaba con pedir disculpas y señalar que vas a tomarte más tiempo en tus futuras decisiones pero parece que el ego no te  permite hacerlo.

Comment: el "nivel de discusión es monótono",  esto puede deberse a que la comunicación no es bidireccional, no se de donde seas, tal vez tengas ideas  que difieren pero cuando se discute de buena forma, debe existir retroalimentación entre ambas partes. Realizo dos preguntas para tener una idea de lo que dices pero no recibo respuesta, al menos hubiera querido saber a que te refieres con "un falacia ad hominen".  En este caso vuelvo nuevamente a repetir, mi decisión fue corregir,  saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys una *falacia ad hominen*  es un argumento con el fin de desacreditar un argumento rival, basándose en las características de esa persona. Se dice que es un argumento ad hominen cuando solo se tiene la intención de desacreditar al rival y no plantear propios argumentos, todo esto con la justificación de temas externos.

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo con lo expuesto por eyllanesc. Todos somos humanos y nos equivocamos, lo que no entiendo es que @Jorgesys no responda a los temas, sino que enmarañe con temas tangenciales, cuando no falseando los hechos. Me recuerda demasiado el caso de [¿Por qué un moderador borró mi comentario en el que preguntaba por una edición?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3900/83) y me hace pensar que sería necesaria una reflexión sobre el uso de las herramientas de moderador cuando hay conflicto de intereses. Un moderador debe poder rendir cuentas y la comunidad necesita que sea así.

Comment: Gracias por la información @Gabitohh , debió decir "una falacia ad hominen" y no usar "un".

Comment: @Elenasys No es la primera vez que realizas tal acción, [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/200871/101499) me la moviste a comentario contando con dos votos positivos

Answer (score 1):

Si un moderador u otro usuario con privilegios en SOes, convierte tu respuesta en comentario y no lo consideras correcto, agrega un comentario preguntando al moderador `@usuario` que te indique el porqué de la acción que realizó. Espera recibir el *feedback* y de ser necesario realiza los ajustes para que la respuesta quede en los términos de [Cómo responder](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

> Procura después de recibir el *feedback*, eliminar el comentario para
> que el mismo no quede 'desvirtuando' la publicación.

*Adicional*, sólo como sugerencia a los usuarios con privilegios, antes de convertir una respuesta donde tengan dudas, dejen un comentario para que mejoren la respuesta basados en [Cómo responder](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) (así el usuario que realizó la respuesta tenga tiempo en el sitio y debería conocer ese apartado); para dar la oportunidad de corregir la respuesta.

Comment: EL camino no es ese sino venir a meta y charlarlo, como se está haciendo. Llenar de mugre las preguntas no sirve y distrae al OP

Comment: **Cesar Romero, eres un usuario miembro desde hace 3 años, pero aun no conoces como realizar una respuesta con los lineamientos definidos en el sitio?, La retroalimentacion generalmente la realizo a usuarios que son nuevos en el sitio, imagina que a cada reporte o publicación que revise tenga que agregar un comentario. Soy el moderador que más tareas de moderacion realiza y con este tipo de publicaciones desvirtuas mi trabajo el cual realizo por gusto y porque deseo un sitio con información de calidad, solo por una actitud de molestia al no ser seleccionada tu respuesta como correcta.**

Comment: **Te vuelvo nuevamente a repetir Cesar Romero, la respuesta la convertí inicialmente a comentario porque inicialmente me pareció tenia baja calidad, esa es la razón de esta acción, pero posteriormente corregí, después de revisar decidí regresarla nuevamente como respuesta, (imagino que aquí deseabas te avisara que la convertí y la regrese), de hecho esta acción no la viste sino después de 3 días cuando volviste a ingresar al sitio.**

Comment: **Te pido por favor tengas cuidado en no hacer alusión de información de la cual no estas completamente seguro como lo que indicaste inicialmente: "luego que fue aceptada su respuesta, volvió a convertir en respuesta lo que había pasado a comentario.". Te informo algo que debes conocer, si realizas una respuesta, no puedes determinar de ninguna forma que tu respuesta debe ser la respuesta aceptada, eso lo determina el OP, el que tu respuesta no fue aceptada incluso no justifica que debes votar negativamente.**

Comment: @Jorgesys Porque tengo 3 años en el sitio, no me puedo equivocar? Sino puedes generar una retroalimentación, pudiste haber permitido que otro usuario me hiciera el comentario. Ahora si indicaste el motivo **la respuesta la convertí inicialmente a comentario porque inicialmente me pareció tenia baja calidad, esa es la razón de esta acción**

Comment: A mi lo que me molesto es que primero agregaste tu respuesta, antes de devolver a respuesta mi comentario **Según el historial se convirtió en comentario desde 5:18 hasta las 16:10** tu respuesta la agregaste **respondida el 29 jul. a las 16:08**. NO me molesto que el OP haya seleccionado tu respuesta, obviamente yo también la elegiría, tiene mejor redacción y colocaste el ejemplo directamente en tu respuesta.

Comment: **Te pido por favor tengas cuidado en no hacer alusión de información de la cual no estas completamente seguro como lo que indicaste inicialmente** Como indique al editar la pregunta, no me consta cuando volví a ingresar me di cuenta del cambio debido al comentario que el OP había agregado en mi respuesta. Pero seria bueno que así como pides que tenga cuidado a lo que hago alusión tu también lo tengas. **de hecho esta acción no la viste sino después de 3 días cuando volviste a ingresar al sitio** eso no es cierto :) ya que ingrese ese mismo día.

Comment: @Alfabravo así como lo propones, no se podrían duplicar las preguntas?

Comment: @CesarRomero en meta se revisa si puede ir a una pregunta genérica o si merece una nueva. No es exactamente igual que en el sitio. En cambio, estoy segurísimo que la pregunta sobre programación no necesita comentarios sobre transparencia en la acción de un moderador.

Comment: @Alfabravo Pienso que en estos casos se pudo usar el chat para tener una discusión alturada del tema, no todos toman las decisiones adecuadas en el momento ya sea porque no se meditó u otro motivo, obviamente el OP ahora conoce el camino correcto en estos casos. Desgraciadamente no todos conocen las reglas de [meta] ni de [so] aun siendo un usuario que usa el sitio diariamente.

Comment: @eyllanesc válido. Pero la gente del común poco usa el chat y meta. El punto es: no ensuciar las preguntas porque esos comentarios que sugiere quien da esta respuesta van a ser marcados (correctamente) como off-topic. Podría ponerse algo en la ayuda para que la gente "sepa" cómo proceder cuando tiene dudas sobre la acción de un moderador.

Comment: @Alfabravo Exacto, eso es lo que se espera del sitio: Que se señale un comentario indicando al usuario el mejor camino y levantar las banderas necesarias para señalar que los comentarios no son necesarios.