# Falta de respeto de un moderador

Tags: discusión

Recientemente respondí está publicación [Mostrar mensaje si un dato no está presente en la base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/610382/mostrar-mensaje-si-un-dato-no-est%c3%a1-presente-en-la-base-de-datos) la primera respuesta que di recibió varios votos negativos, los cuales inicialmente no entendí(pero eso no es lo importante), resulta que después de varios debates con otros miembros de la comunidad decido eliminar mi primera respuesta y dar una donde le responda al usuario su duda, pero a la vez le informo que lo que pretende hacer no es una buena práctica, entonces el moderador @JorgeSys mostrando una total falta de respeto hacia mi decide eliminar mi nueva respuesta, y vuelve a hacer visible mi respuesta incorrecta, no se que pretendia el con esto, pero por muy moderador que sea no es quien para perjudicarme de esa forma. Espero haya sido una equivocación.

Nota: solo los usuarios con más de 10k podrán ver las respuestas eliminadas.

Comment: Eres un usuario que lleva tiempo en el sitio, evita eliminar tus respuestas para agregar otras, simplemente mejoralas. Desde hace varios meses realizas prácticas que no son apropiadas, me parece que solo por tratar de obtener mayor reputación, cuando les ponen un -1 parece que les quitan una vida, trata,  por favor trata de leer como funciona el sitio, no trates de inventar nuevas reglas.

Comment: No, @Jorgesys error, yo no llevo meses haciendo malas prácticas cuidadito con eso, es verdad que desde hace un tiempo he editado varias de mis respuestas para mejorarlas, eso no es malo y nada me prohíbe hacerlo, respecto a eso el equipo de moderación me pidió y me explicó que eso llenaba la página principal de mis ediciones, haciendo menos visible otras, recepcione ese mensaje y les dije que iba a ser más cuidadoso, pero ninguna regla del sitio dice que no debo editar mis publicaciones, de hecho en un día se pueden editar hasta 30 publicaciones, yo no hice nada incorrecto, no desvíes el tema

Comment: Tal vez no lo hagas con la intención de obtener votos, pero lamentablemente es lo que parece. En todo caso, no veo dónde está la falta de respeto. El moderador hizo lo que se supone debe hacer en un caso como el tuyo o cualquiera. No hay que victimizarse. A mi me han borrado gran cantidad de comentarios y nunca he reclamado nada, porque sinceramente entiendo que mis comentarios han estado fuera de lugar, muchas veces a propósito y otras no tanto. Pero todos pasamos por allí. No entiendo hasta cuando hacer POST en Meta para reclamar puntos. Pasar página y a otro lío. O te dan dinero por puntos?

Comment: @ElTroll tus comentarios son borrados pq eres un troll, que se le va a hacer, ademas esta vez fue una respuesta no un comentario, yo he recibido votos negativos que han estado bien dados y no pasa nada, yo salto cuando veo que hay malas practicas, y para que veas muchas veces en esos casos hasta los propios moderadores se han puesto de mi parte, porque saben que algo hubo mal, te repito sigues enfrascado en que se trata del puntaje y no es asi, se trata de comunicar, de informar, de darse a entender, eso si es moderar, otra cosa es actuar como policia

Comment: La verdad que no veo la necesidad de hacer tanto show... si el usuario borra una respuesta con votos negativos esto no afectara su reputación (no le va a devolver los puntos), si el usuario borra sus respuestas, a la larga el sistema se va a encargar restringiendo el uso del sitio para dar respuesta (no se requiere moderación), el actuar de la moderación basado en prácticas de borrado esta fuera de contexto por que el sitio tiene la capacidad de moderar esto.

Comment: Sin embargo que un moderador mueva cosas sin darte una explicación si deja mucho que decir profesionalmente hablando … y escudarse en que un moderador no necesita dar explicaciones al moderar… es aún más oscuro que gris… están jugando con el tiempo de una persona… que voluntariamente ofrece su tiempo a responder.

Comment: Que les cuestan dejar un chat: *hey fulanito estás haciendo esto… y no lo veo bien, tienes algún argumento… porque si no me voy a meter a moderar…* conociendo que el usuario participa activamente del chat y del sitio…

Comment: incluso yo recuerdo que @gbianchi en algunos momento lo ha hecho, primero nos pregunta en el chat, por que de eso se trata una comunidad ... de comunicarce ... si un moderador no puede o se niega, pierde todo sentido su funciona dentro del sitio...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover de eso se trata de comunicarse, no de si me dieron +1 o -1 como erroneamente asumiron otros usuarios en sus comentarios, el que tenga dudas de lo que significa la palabra moderador o moderacion que la busque en un diccionario

Comment: Es que eso de la reputacion es una cortina de humo para sacar de contexto el escenario ... ya tienen esa mania ... no entiendo por que tratan de minificar o restarle importancia a las quejas y las cosas que sucede en el sitio ... en lugar de aceptar los errores y mejorar ... buscan lo contrario.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover has expuesto tus inquietudes de mejoras al CM o en https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?

Comment: @Jorgesys ya respondi esa pregunta ...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Me imagino no aceptaron tus propuestas, consejos y mejoras, ¿Por qué no las aceptarían?

Comment: ¿¿Lo banearon por esto???

Comment: Alguien sabe cual fue el desencadenante del ban?

Comment: Yo lo que pienso de todo esto es que si un moderador te elimina una respuesta, deberia dejar **antes** de eliminar la pregunta un comentario para mejorarla/decir el motivo por la cual va a ser eliminada, tal como ha comentado @Japv.

Answer (score 6):

No es correcto borrar una respuesta con puntaje negativo para agregar otra que es esencialmente es la misma como nueva respuesta pero limpia de puntaje. La mejora de tu respuesta ameritaba una edición de la original, en ningún caso una nueva respuesta.

Dudo que exista una norma explicita en el reglamento, pero es evidente que es una forma de burlar el sistema de votación.

Aquí en Meta hay una publicación al respecto donde Miquel Coll aclara que no se permite este tipo de acción
https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1492/301324

Miquel Coll en ese entonces era moderador diamantado, por lo que podemos asumir que lo indicado por él, es el protocolo para estos casos.

---

offtopic:

Hace algunos meses algunos usuarios advertimos que el centro de ayuda necesita de mejoras. Para mi este es un claro ejemplo, un usuario "hace algo" y le dicen que lea como funciona el sitio, en el centro de ayuda no dice nada al respecto, entonces hay que bucear en Meta para encontrar una situación similar, luego encuentras una respuesta y tienes que evaluar si lo que dice el usuario es su opinión personal o es "oficial". De suerte (porque yo no estaba en ese tiempo) recuerdo que al parece era moderador, entonces hay que buscar si eso que dijo fue en el tiempo que él lo era, entonces a bucear nuevamente a buscar la línea de tiempo de diamantados.

Y luego dicen que los que no cumplen las reglas es porque no leyeron las normas.

Comment: Agradezco tu tiempo, en ningún momento busque burlar el sistema de votos, simplemente decidí borrar lo que estaba mal y empezar de cero (ni que lo hiciera todos los días), la moderación no actuó bien, el debió avisarme, ponerme un mensaje, mensaje que envió después que empecé a hablar de lo sucedido, si yo no hubiera saltado el no habría escrito ese mensaje, parece que se dió cuenta que se le fue la mano. Pero además repito la respuesta es mia, el no tiene que borrarla, no tiene ningún derecho y menos sin intentar razonar conmigo, hombre yo lo hubiera entendido, pero a la fuerza si que no

Comment: @Japv No ha sido mi intención señalar que tu **buscabas** burlar el sistema, sino que el acto mismo es una burla al sistema (incluso sin la intención de ello). Del actuar de la moderación evité referirme, porque hasta que tu lo mencionaste desconocía si hubo advertencia o no.

Comment: Pero como aclaración, los moderadores están justamente para esto, para resolver temas que de forma automática no es posible hacerlo y dentro de sus competencias está el borrar publicaciones. Son humanos y pueden equivocarse tanto en forma como en fondo, por eso es mejor tomarse un tiempo antes de aclarar la situación.

Comment: @Yussef el potetsad del usuario hacer lo que la plataforma le permita, si quiere borrar su cuenta y 15 dias despues crear otra, no hay ningun problema la plataforma lo permite, asi mismo pasa con las respuestas, el usuario puede hacer lo que la plataforma le permita si quiere borrarla y crear una nueva, cual es el problema... que la plataforma lo bloquea ... eso es su problema ... respuesta borrada no afecta en nada al sitio...

Comment: ademas borrar una pregunta no vurla el sistema de votos por ese motivo he votado negativamente esta respuesta.

Comment: **Los comentarios han sido [movidos al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150515/discussion-on-answer-by-yussef-falta-de-respeto-de-un-moderador); por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí.** Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los [propósitos de los comentarios](/help/privileges/comment). Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una [respuesta](/help/how-to-answer), o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

Answer (score 3):

Primero que nada debemos aceptar que nadie es perfecto, usuarios y moderadores podemos llegar a cometer errores, pero estoy seguro que no existe mayor virtud que aceptar los errores cuando los cometemos.

1. no hay una norma que le prohíba borrar una respuesta con votos negativos o positivos a un usuario. Y esto debe quedar bien claro que el mismo sistema de auto moderación del sitio lleva esta métrica interna y restringe a los usuarios que borran sus respuesta y no las mejoran. El querer moderar esto, debe tener un sustento, no es normal tanta atención.
2. Ahora apelo a la cultura de COMUNIDAD en donde le demos un mayor valor a ser comunicativos antes de tomar decisiones a ligera. La mayoría de controversias se dan por que alguien hace algo que jode a otro, sin preguntarle o comentarle.
3. Seamos sincero debemos RESPETAR EL TIEMPO DEDICADO de todos, tanto de la moderación como el de los usuarios.
4. No restemos importancia a estas situaciones, recuerden que la tuerca no se aprieta con una sola vuelta… ir puliendo detalles del sitio mejorara la cultura en él y mejorara el sitio.

**Update:**

Como usuario preocupado por la buena cultura y prácticas en la comunidad, he indagado más sobre el tema sobre todo porque @jarv fue baneado por 7 días, en mi dialogo con él hasta este momento de esta edición no se le envió ninguna justificación por correo o chat de la razón del baneo.

Entiendo que la forma en que él ha abordado el tema, se puede sentir un poco agresivo... pero también entiendo su frustración, la cual desconozco si la Moderación tiene la capacidad de contextualizar antes de tomar acciones.

Por otro lado, las acciones de Bumping de @jarv no fueron a propósito, ya que su postura es que el no necesita más reputación, lo cual entiendo... que el al editar preguntas y respuestas, estas salgan en la página principal es algo colateral que hace el sistema automaticamente y que perjudica a los nuevos usuarios... y al sitio, una vez conociendo esto, reduce al recurrencia en ediciones.

**Lo dicho en parrafos anteriores no tiene relación alguna con respecto a la acciones de la moderación:** 
1- eliminar una buena respuesta. 
2- volver a hacer visible una mala respuesta. 
**Que es el escenario de la queja o reclamo realizado.**

Vuelvo y repito, nada de este show hubiera sido necesario si hubiera existido una mejor comunicación entre la moderación y el usuario. Entender que está pasando, si alguien debe detener una práctica que el mismo sitio sugiere es contradictorio hasta que se argumenta y se explica correctamente...

Decir que por ser Moderador, no requiere dar explicaciones, no saca a la comunidad de la ignorancia que puede orillar a los usuarios a malas prácticas ...

**Argumento no relacionado al baneo:**

El sitio sugiere la edición y mejora de preguntas y respuestas... lo que no se dice y que puede pasar es que alguien con un alto número de preguntas/respuesta realice ediciones a esta de una forma muy recurrente que al final afecte negativamente al sitio... esto no está en la ayuda... y si es el motivo del baneo, no considero que sea adecuado como acción tomada.

Aun nos mantenemos en espera de si habrá alguna aclaratoria sobre el baneo del compañero.

Comment: Curioso que el resto de los moderadores no haya intervenido en apoyo de su compañero, hasta ahora han sido neutrales, no se si pq no le han dado importancia al asunto o simplemente decidieron no intervenir

Comment: es lo que normalmente pasa ... imaginate que no estan de acuerdo con lo que digo jajaja donde solo trato de decir que debemos mejorar ... osea que no estan deacuerdo con que mejoremos ...

Comment: @Japv HAHAHAHAHA! Es que por el momento únicamente estoy yo, no estamos a toda hora moderando, ni dando asistencia personal. Lo siento, pero también tenemos otras ocupaciones.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover has expuesto tus inquietudes de mejoras al CM o en https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?

Comment: **Los comentarios han sido [movidos al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150549/discussion-on-answer-by-francisco-nunez-ia-lover-falta-de-respeto-de-un-moderado); por favor, no continuar la discusión aquí.** Antes de publicar un comentario bajo este, por favor revisa los [propósitos de los comentarios](/help/privileges/comment). Los comentarios que no pidan clarificaciones o sugieran mejoras normalmente deben ser publicados como una [respuesta](/help/how-to-answer), o en el [chat]. Los comentarios que continúen la discusión podrán ser eliminados.

Comment: Buena respuesta, @FranciscoNuñezIALover. Estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo en que la moderacion y el usuario tienen que tener mejor comunicacion. Ya le he puesto mi +1 a la respuesta. Gracias por aclarirlo todo tan bien. Un saludo y gracias otra vez

Comment: Sería bueno que aclararán el tema del baneo, queda la sensación de que algo no cuadra